# Fast way to find exponent of nearest superior power of 2

Tags: java, performance

If I have a number *a*, I want the value of *x* in *b*=2^*x*, where *b* is the next power of 2 greater than *a*.

In case you missed the tag, this is Java, and *a* is an int. I'm looking for the fastest way to do this. My solution thusfar is to use bit-twiddling to get *b*, then do (int)(log(*b*)/log(2)), but I feel like there has to be a faster method that doesn't involve dividing two floating-point numbers.

Comment: What's the range of `x` values? What's the type of `a`?

Comment: As I said in the question, _a_ is an int. _x_ is strictly non-negative.

Comment: @Andy: Where did you say it in the question? You said you have a *number* `a`. It could have been a `short`, a `long` or even be `BigInteger`. Can it be `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, in which case `x` can be 32, but no higher?

Comment: "In case you missed the tag, this is Java, and a is an int." And yes, _x_ is from 0 to 32.

Comment: I've assumed you mean "next power of 2 greater than *or equal to a*", and that *a* is unsigned, and that *a* is 32 bits.

Comment: You're correct about greater than or equal to. Unfortunately, there is no `unsigned` modifier in Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding up to nearest power of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-up-to-nearest-power-of-2)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What about `a == 0 ? 0 : 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(a - 1)`?  That avoids floating point entirely.  If you know `a` is never 0, you can leave off the first part.

Comment: I know _a_ is nonzero, so I can just go with `32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(a - 1)`. This looks perfect. Never knew that method existed. Thank you!

Comment: How about for long?

Comment: `32` -> `Integer.SIZE`

Comment: Note that `1 << (Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(x - 1))` gives 1 for negative values and 0 (if your array size is 1 rather than 0, you can multiply it by 2 to create a bigger array); for powers of 2 it returns the same power of 2, e.g. 8 --> 8 (which, strictly speaking, is not the "next superior" power of 2, but 2*\*N --> 2*\*N is what is usually needed). For Integer.MAX_VALUE=2147483647 it returns Integer.MIN_VALUE=-2147483648.

Comment: (Continuing my other comment) Integer shifts are tricky: only the 5 least-significant bits are used, the rest is ignored. `1<<33==1<<1025==1<<1==2`. For 0 and negative numbers, the code `Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(x - 1)` returns 32, binary 10_0000, and the 5 bits that are not ignored by `<<` are all zero

Answer (score 14):

If anyone is looking for some "bit-twiddling" code that Andy mentions, that could look something like this: (if people have better ways, you should share!)

```
    public static int nextPowerOf2(final int a)
    {
        int b = 1;
        while (b < a)
        {
            b = b << 1;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: Downvote. Doesn't answer the question. The question is: "I want the value of x in b=2^x, where b is the next power of 2 greater than or equal to a." (See comment by OP for "greater than or equal to" part.) This answer produces b, not x.

Comment: @jona That&#39;s true, if you want x you can just count the number of iterations of the while loop and return that.  I don&#39;t know what you&#39;d name that method though :-)

Answer (score 9):

Not necessarily faster, but one liner:

```
int nextPowerOf2(int num)
{
    return num == 1 ? 1 : Integer.highestOneBit(num - 1) * 2;
}
```

Comment: Downvote. Doesn't answer the question. The question is: "I want the value of x in b=2^x, where b is the next power of 2 greater than or equal to a." (See comment by OP for "greater than or equal to" part.) This answer produces b, not x.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an answer that works for integers or floating point, both of these should work:

I would think that `Math.floor(Math.log(a) * 1.4426950408889634073599246810019) + 1` would be your best bet if you don't want to do bit twiddling.

If you do want to bit-twiddle, you can use `Double.doubleToLongBits(a)` and then just extract the exponent. I'm thinking `((Double.doubleRawToLongBits(a) >>> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1022` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

just do the following:

extract the highest bit by using this method (modified from hdcode):

```
int msb(int x) {
   if (pow2(x)) return x;
   x = x | (x >> 1);
   x = x | (x >> 2);
   x = x | (x >> 4);
   x = x | (x >> 8);
   x = x | (x >> 16);
   x = x | (x >> 24);
   return x - (x >> 1);
}

int pow2(int n) {
   return (n) & (n-1) == 0;
}
```

combining both functions into this function to get a number 'b', that is the next power of 2 of a given number 'a':

```
int log2(int x) {
    int pow = 0;
    if(x >= (1 << 16)) { x >>= 16; pow +=  16;}
    if(x >= (1 << 8 )) { x >>=  8; pow +=   8;}
    if(x >= (1 << 4 )) { x >>=  4; pow +=   4;}
    if(x >= (1 << 2 )) { x >>=  2; pow +=   2;}
    if(x >= (1 << 1 )) { x >>=  1; pow +=   1;}
    return pow;
}
```

kind regards,
dave

Comment: Downvote. Doesn't answer the question. The question is: "I want the value of x in b=2^x, where b is the next power of 2 greater than or equal to a." (See comment by OP for "greater than or equal to" part.) This answer produces b, not x.

Answer (score 0):

How about divide-and-conquer? As in:

```
b = 0;
if (a >= 65536){a /= 65536; b += 16;}
if (a >= 256){a /= 256; b += 8;}
if (a >= 16){a /= 16; b += 4;}
if (a >= 4){a /= 4; b += 2;}
if (a >= 2){a /= 2; b += 1;}
```

Assuming `a` is unsigned, the divides should just be bit-shifts.

A binary IF-tree with 32 leaves should be even faster, getting the answer in 5 comparisons. Something like:

```
if (a >= (1<<0x10)){
  if (a >= (1<<0x18)){
    if (a >= (1<<0x1C)){
      if (a >= (1<<0x1E)){
        if (a >= (1<<0x1F)){
          b = 0x1F;
        } else {
          b = 0x1E;
        }
      } else {
        if (a >= (1<<0x1D)){
          b = 0x1D;
        } else {
          b = 0x1C;
        }
      }
   etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Java provides a function that rounds down to the nearest power of 2. Thus `a!=Integer.highestOneBit(a)?2*Integer.highestOneBit(a):a` is a slightly prettier solution, assuming a is positive.

Storing `Integer.highestOneBit(a)` in a variable may further improve performance and readability.

Comment: storing same calculation in a variable if no changes to the arguments happen in between, is something the compiler does by default, no?

Comment: @Phil the compiler would need to know that the function has no side-effects. I personally would not bank on it.

Answer (score -1):

To add to Jeremiah Willcock's answer, if you want the value of the power of 2 itself, then you will want:

```
(int) Math.pow(2, (a == 0) ? 0 : 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(numWorkers));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code for the same. Will this be faster?

```
 int a,b,x,y;
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    a = inp.nextInt();
    y = (int) (Math.log(a)/Math.log(2));
    x = y +1;
    System.out.println(x);
```