# What does this bit-manipulating function do?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
unsigned long ccNextPOT(unsigned long x){

    x = x - 1;
    x = x | (x >> 1);
    x = x | (x >> 2);
    x = x | (x >> 4);
    x = x | (x >> 8);
    x = x | (x >>16);
    return x + 1;
}
```

Comment: i know it works well, but i want to know which algorithm it use.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding up to next power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-up-to-next-power-of-2)

Answer (score 3):

The OR and SHIFT statements fills with ones all bits of `x` to the right of most significant bit (up to 32 bits). Together with the pre-decrement and post-increment statements, this computes (as the function name suggets) the next power-of-two number, equal or greater than the given number (if `x` is greater than 0 and less than 2^32)

Comment: The pre-decrement ensures inputs of zero and powers of two are mapped onto themselves.