# Efficient computation of a power of 2

Tags: c, performance, math, optimization

I have a requirement to compute `k` as the smallest power of 2 which is >= an integer value, `n` (`n` is always > 0)

currently I am using:

```
#define log2(x) log(x)/log(2)
#define round(x) (int)(x+0.5)

k = round(pow(2,(ceil(log2(n)))));
```

this is in a performance critical function

Is there a more computationally efficient way of calculating `k`?

Comment: If you are using GCC, you can use `1 << CHAR_BIT * sizeof x - __builtin_clz(x)`, provided `x` has type `unsigned int` or, on normal systems, `int`. There is also `__builtin_clzl` for `unsigned long`. Some non-GCC compilers also support this extension. This will be faster than any of the other answers so far on processors that have a “find first bit set” instruction.

Comment: note edit from '> an integer value' to '>= an integer value'

Comment: Now everybody has to change their answers again. :-)

Comment: demand a stack overflow 'undo' button...

Comment: For the code in my comment above, change `(x)` to `(x-1)`.

Comment: There is a “rollback” button in the editing interface. Answers which were changed solely to address the greater-than versus greater-than-or-equal-to issue can be rolled back with this. Answers which had other changes will need manual editing.

Comment: Unrelated to an answer, but worth mentioning to anyone who comes upon this and doesn't know better: it's wise to ditch the +0.5 and (int) cast, and instead use the floor() or ceiling() functions in calculations like this.  Of course, logarithms are still slow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding up to next power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-up-to-next-power-of-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int calculate_least_covering_power_of_two(int x)
{
  int k = 1;
  while( k < x ) k = k << 1;
  return k;
}
```

Comment: benchmark this with the branch-free version, I suspect you'll find this isn't the most efficient way to do it.  But, it will work.

Comment: @RandyHoward i've done that and theres no discernible difference (for my application) so I think I'll stick with this answer as its simpler

Comment: @Randy: this naive method is very easy to understand and must not be ported to 64- (128-, ...)bit machines. It is also helpful to understand it first, then move on to the branch-free version. 

**The branch-free version will _surely_ be more efficient for uniformly distributed 32-bit-integers.**, but may be a bit slower for small integers. 
Also, I've given a "+1" to your post, and it was a nice surprise that my post was accepted )

Comment: @alex-shesterov could you explain the problem with porting your function to a 64-bit machine?

Comment: @Hiett: the function from _this_ answer works for 16, 32, 64, whatever-bit systems without any changes; its complexity (number of iterations) is equal to the number of system-bits (i.e. 16, 32, 64 or whatever) _in worst case_ - i.e. it is linear in the number of bits. The function from RandyHoward's answer needs to be ported to 64-bit-platforms by adding `x |= x>>32`, and its complexity is logarithmic _in worst as well as in best case_. My _estimate_ is that the function by RandyHoward is 15% faster than this one in average on 32-bit systems.

Comment: @alex-shesterov thanks for clarification - typically my values for x are small, < 50. I think perhaps that is why i see little difference in performance between the 2 functions. Having worked through a few clp2 examples on paper though i can see it is quite elegant

Answer (score 9):

```
/* returns greatest power of 2 less than or equal to x, branch-free */
/* Source: Hacker's Delight, First Edition. */
int
flp2(int x)
{
    x = x | (x>>1);
    x = x | (x>>2);
    x = x | (x>>4);
    x = x | (x>>8);
    x = x | (x>>16);
    return x - (x>>1);
}
```

It's entertaining to study it and see how it works.  I think the only way for you to know for sure which of the solutions you see will be optimal for your situation is to use all of them in a text fixture and profile it and see which is most efficient for your purpose.

Being branch-free, this one is likely to be quite good performance-wise relative to some others, but you should test it directly to be sure.

If you want the least power of two greater than or equal to X, you can use a slightly different solution:

```
unsigned
clp2(unsigned x)
{
    x = x -1;
    x = x | (x >> 1);
    x = x | (x >> 2);
    x = x | (x >> 4);
    x = x | (x >> 8);
    x = x | (x >> 16);
    return x + 1;
}
```

Comment: This is nice, since the 'left most' 1 is the answer the goal is to 0 all other bits, this does it nicely. You will need an extra line for 64 bit numbers.

Comment: Ah yes, you wanted something else, let me post it.

Comment: If you use the `x |= x >>1; ...` form, you can get rid of the parentheses, since the assignment operators have very low precedence.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- thank you, I've edited to include a similar routine that finds a power greater than or equal to X, which I think matches the original question better.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This answer returns the greatest power of 2 less than or equal to `x`. To change that to the least power of 2 greater than `x`, simply left shift the result by 1.

Comment: @RandyHoward Note that the question asks for greater, not greater than or equal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The greatest power of 2 less than or equal to 33 is 32. If you left shift that by 1, you get 64, not 128.

Comment: @28OZ28: You are correct, shifting the result of the original code by 1 bit works.

Comment: Yes.  Moving the end result up or down by one power of 2, (depending on the actual intent) is pretty straightforward.  Hopefully Hiett will be able to use the information for the specific needs of his program.

Comment: am i right in thinking these 'hacker delight' solutions are not so portable then, i.e. 32 bit and 64 bit architectures?

Comment: i guess a check on sizeof(unsigned int) would be required?

Comment: Don't let the term "hacker" fool you.  These are quite useful.  They are certainly more portable than compiler specific solutions, or CPU-specific instruction solutions, for example.  These bit shifting solutions have to know how large an int or unsigned int is on a given platform for them to work correctly.  That's true of anything like this though.  You can determine the size of various data types at compile time though, and make adjustments (or use an alternate implementation) for other architectures if you need extreme ranges.

Comment: @RandyHoward is an int still 32 bits on a 64 bit machine? additional line would only be needed for a long (64 bits)? wouldn;t the type checking for the input parameter prevent any problems - e.g. if its an int it should be 32 bits?

Comment: @Hiett since right shifting 0 is still 0 you can add the extra line if you need to cater for both 32-bit and 64-bit. the result for 32 bit will still be correct and only waste a few instructions

Answer (score 2):

```
lim = 123;
n = 1;
while( ( n = n << 1 ) <= lim );
```

Multiply your number by 2 until it's bigger than lim.

Left shift of one multiplies value by 2.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Tnx for noticing, fixed...  ( doesn't work for lim = zero but that can be solved using if() )

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  You can calculate this by simply taking the number in question, and using bit-shifts to determine the power of 2.
Right-shifting takes all the bits in the number and moves them to the right, dropping the far right (least significant) digit.  It is equivalent to performing an integer division by 2. Left-shifting a value moves all the bits to the left, dropping the bits that shift off the left end, and adding zeroes to the right end, effectively multiplying the value by 2.
 So if you count how many times you need to right shift before the number reaches  zero, you have calculated the integer portion of the base 2 logarithm.  Then use it to create your result by left-shifting the value 1 that many times.

```
  int CalculateK(int val)
  {
      int cnt = 0;
      while(val > 0)
      {
           cnt++;
           val = val >> 1;
      }
      return 1 << cnt;
  }
```

EDIT: Alternatively, and a bit simpler: you don't have to calculate the count

```
  int CalculateK(int val)
  {
      int res = 1;
      while(res <= val) res <<= 1;
      return res ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
k = 1 << (int)(ceil(log2(n)));
```

You can take advantage of the fact that binary digits represent powers of two (1 is 1, 10 is 2, 100 is 4, etc). Shifting 1 left by the exponent of 2 gives you the same value, but it's much faster.

Although if you can somehow avoid the ceil(log2(n)) you will see a much larger performance increase.

Comment: This code does not compile because `ceil` has type `double` and cannot be used with `<<`. When a cast to `int` is inserted and `n` is 32, this code produces 32, but the desired result is 64.

Comment: I added a cast to int to the example. I'm not sure why the desired result for n=32 would be 64... maybe I did not understand the original question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, it appears to be asking for the smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to n. 32 is equal to 32. But maybe I am still misunderstanding. Either way, Randy Howard's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Source: hackersdelight.org

```
/* altered to: power of 2 which is greater than an integer value */

unsigned clp2(unsigned x) {
   x = x | (x >> 1);
   x = x | (x >> 2);
   x = x | (x >> 4);
   x = x | (x >> 8);
   x = x | (x >>16);
   return x + 1;
}
```

Keep in mind you will need to add:

```
x = x | (x >> 32);
```

For 64bit numbers.