# C# How do you round number to closest number in a geometric sequence

Tags: c#

I am trying to round a number to the closest number in a geometric sequence having a factor of 2 between each number.

Lets say I have:

```
int num = 30;
```

I would need "num" to be rounded to 32

Comment: Do you need the next power of two, or the closest?

Comment: any chance you've tried anything other than `int num = 30;` ? could we see some of that?

Comment: Related: [Rounding up to nearest power of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-up-to-nearest-power-of-2)

Comment: The closest so if "num" was equal to 33, I would need it to be rounded to 32 instead of 64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double logValue = Math.Log(30, 2);   
double ceilingValue= Math.Round(logValue);

double result = Math.Pow(2, ceilingValue);
```

Comment: I tried the code it worked well but only rounded to the next number in sequence instead of going to the closest number.

Comment: @MattJ Yes use Math.Round instead of Math.Ceiling. Like in my edit.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this method will consider 23 to be closer to 32 than to 16.