# 'qNextPowerOfTwo' was not declared in this scope - Qt

Tags: linux, qt, qtmath

I recently installed Qt in Lubuntu and I'm getting the following error

[image: Error showing that function qNextPowerOfTwo is not declared in this scope]

This function is provided by QtMath library which IS included in the file.

[image]

any advice here? I have the same project in Windows but I have no such problem.
Thanks for your time.
Best regards

Peter

P.S. I enclose the .pro file the relevant code to the question is already in the images. I'm using Qt 5.2.1 (GCC 4.8.2, 32bit)

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-04-26T18:35:07
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

TARGET = WaveMod
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES +=\
    mainwindow.cpp \
trace_ex.cpp \
trace_group_ex.cpp \
qcustomplot.cpp \
main.cpp \
fft_complx.cpp \
geom_ex.cpp


HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
trace_ex.h \
trace_group_ex.h \
qcustomplot.h \
fft_complx.h \
geom_ex.h \

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
trace_ex.ui \
trace_group_ex.ui \
geom_ex.ui

DISTFILES += \
geom_map.qml
```

Comment: What version of qt do you have?

Comment: show .pro and share your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation of the function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmath.html#qNextPowerOfTwo) it says.

> This function was introduced in Qt 5.4.

Try upgrading your Qt setup if you need that function, or have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466204/2628463).

Comment: Thanks Martin, That's it once I upgraded the error is gone.