# JavaScript function to check how many bits are required to encode a number?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I have the following problem. Here is sample input/output data:

- i: 0, o: 1 (0)
- i: 1, o: 1 (1)
- i: 2, o: 2 (10)
- i: 3, o: 2 (11)
- i: 4, o: 3 (100)
- i: 5, o: 3 (101)
- i: 6, o: 3 (110)
- i: 7, o: 3 (111)

However, that is just using the smallest number of bits to encode the number. I want something slightly different, having a hard time wrapping my head around it. I want the output to be a power of 2.

- i: 0, o: 2 (00)
- i: 1, o: 2 (01)
- i: 2, o: 2 (10)
- i: 3, o: 2 (11)
- i: 4, o: 4 (0100)
- i: 5, o: 4 (0101)
- i: 6, o: 4 (0110)
- i: 7, o: 4 (0111)
- i: 8, o: 4 (1000)
- ...
- i.... o: 8
- ...
- i.... o: 16
- ...

How do I write a function that takes an integer in JavaScript, and returns to me `o` for that number? One that is doing it efficiently and not converting things to strings and using random JS helper functions :)

Comment: I think the second sequence is just the first sequence rounded up to the nearest power of 2.

Comment: Uh, `1` would be a power of `2` as well. Why don't you want that?

Comment: Sorry, I just want even numbers power of 2 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're into bit fiddling, you could [find the position of the MSB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671815/1048572) then [find the next power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466204/1048572) (with an exceptional case for the two values below 2).

We can also find a closed form:

```
const bits = x => Math.floor(1+Math.log2(x))
const npot = x => Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log2(x)))
const f = x => x < 2 ? 2 : npot(bits(x))
```

However, given the small number of powers of two in range, it's much easier and faster to just use a condition ladder:

```
const f = x => {
  if (x < 2**2) return 2;
  if (x < 2**4) return 4;
  if (x < 2**8) return 8;
  if (x < 2**16) return 16;
  if (x < 2**32) return 32;
  return 64;
}
```

(When working with bigints, use a loop for that…)

Answer (score -1):

If your intention is to write the function, if there is no correlation between the inputs you might have to iterate through the 64 bits one at a time using the binary operators. And if you want just the 2nd use case check if it already a power of 2 or not, and do vice versa. To check for power of 2.
n~(n-1) == 0

P.S in mobile so mind the bad editting.