# How to get the highest value from a Delphi set?

Tags: algorithm, delphi, set

Is there any way to extract the highest (or lowest) value in a set?  For example, if I have the following "set of byte":

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 28, 199]
```

is there any function I could run on that and get back 199 as the result?

EDIT: There's an obvious brute-force solution involving a for..in loop.  If possible, I'd like to find a better way than that.

Answer (score 15):

A loop really is the formally correct way to do it.

```
type
  TSetType = set of TEnumType;

function HighestMember(const s: TSetType): TEnumType;
begin
  for Result := High(Result) downto Low(Result) do
    if Result in s then
      exit;
  raise Exception.Create('empty sets have no highest member');
end;
```

Any other kind of solution will require type-casting or assembler, both of which force you to lose type-safety — they go "outside the language," so to speak.

If you can guarantee that your set has no more than 32 possible elements, then the set can be overlaid with an ordinary integer, and your question is equivalent to asking for the position of the highest bit set in a 32-bit integer. That's been asked here before, pretty much:

- [Position of least significant bit that is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set)

If you don't have a 32-element restriction on the set type, then you have Delphi's 256-element limit, and any bit-twiddling solution will need to handle a 32-*byte* input.

Comment: A 256-max-count loop to find the highest bit set is not brute force. An attack on the DoD or trying to decrypt RSA is brute force. This is the best solution. Write your code for readability first, speed second (and only if you discover a real bottleneck).

Comment: That kind of relies on the internal implementation of a set as a bitset doesn't it? Otherwise I would prefer looping over the elements of the set instead of looping over all possible values...

Comment: Smasher, there is no way to enumerate the contents of a set except by checking every possible value. Internally, that's how the "for-in" loop works. The method I demonstrated with code does not rely on any internal representation, only that the set be finite. Any bit-twiddling solution does rely on the internal representation, but that's a very safe assumption: Delhi sets have never changed; they're the same as they were back in Turbo Pascal.

Answer (score 6):

Sets are unordered, so you're not going to get much better than a loop. If you're constantly looking up the min/max value of a set, then use a [heap data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), which provides O(1) lookup to get the min/max value and O(log n) lookup on any other value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little quicker version that uses knowledge of the internal structure of the byte set.

```
type
  TByteSet = set of Byte;

function HighestElement(const ByteSet: TByteSet): Byte;
type
  TSetBytes = array[0..SizeOf(TByteSet) - 1] of Byte;
var
  I, J: Integer;
  B: Byte;
  SetBytes: TSetBytes;
begin
  if ByteSet <> [] then
  begin
    SetBytes := TSetBytes(ByteSet);
    // Start at the top and work down, one byte at a time
    for I := SizeOf(TByteSet) - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      // Any bits set here
      B := SetBytes[I];
      if B <> 0 then
      begin
        Result := I * 8;
        for J := 0 to 7 do
          if (B shr J) and 1 <> 0 then
          begin
            Result := Result + J;
            Exit;
          end;
      end;
    end;
  end else
    // No elements set
end;
```

You can change the type of the set, TByteSet, to nearly any set type, and this function should still work. Just replace TByteSet within the function decl and body with the type of your set. You can also modify it to return the actual element type if using a set of AnsiChar, or a set of some enumeration type. To get the lowest value, change the "I" for loop to "0 to SizeOf(TByteSet) - 1" and the if test in the "J" loop to "if (B shl J) and $80 <> 0"

Comment: Hmm, besides "platform" and "deprecated" we are also going to need a "endianunsafe" directive in time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nearly the same, but shorter:

```
type
  TByteSet = set of Byte;

function MaxSet(S: TByteSet): Byte;
var
  CardArr: Array [0..7] of Cardinal absolute S;
  i: Byte;
begin
  i := 7;
  while (i > 0) AND (CardArr[i] = 0) do
    Dec(i);
  Result := i + Floor(Log2(CardArr[i]));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Highest and lowest, not use of Math unit:

```
type
  TCharSet = set of Char;

function MaxOfSet(aSet: TCharSet):Char;
var
  Data:array[0..SizeOf(TCharSet)-1] of Byte absolute aSet;
  i,r:Byte;
begin
  if aSet<>[] then begin
     i:=SizeOf(TCharSet)-1;
     while (i>0) and (Data[i]=0) do
        Dec(i);
     r:=i*8;
     i:=Data[i];
     while (i and $80)=0 do begin
        i:=i shl 1;
        Dec(r)
     end;
     Result:=Chr(r+7)
  end
  else
     raise Exception.Create('Unable to extract max value from an empty set');
end;

function MinOfSet(aSet: TCharSet):Char;
var
  Data:array[0..SizeOf(TCharSet)-1] of Byte absolute aSet;
  i,r:Byte;
begin
  if aSet<>[] then begin
     i:=0;
     while (i<SizeOf(TCharSet)-1) and (Data[i]=0) do
        Inc(i);
     r:=i*8;
     i:=Data[i];
     while (i and 1)=0 do begin
        i:=i shr 1;
        Inc(r)
     end;
     Result:=Chr(r)
  end
  else
     raise Exception.Create('Unable to extract min value from an empty set');
end;
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer. It would be helpful than just a piece of code.