# fastest code to generate unique base62 hashes

Tags: c#, hash, bit.ly, tinyurl

hey guys i want to generate unique base62 hashes - something similar to what tinyurl and bit.ly do using c#. this would be based on an auto increment field ID of type bigint (like most of these sites)

min chars would be 1 and max chars would be 6... if you had to write the fastest code (least amount of cpu usage) in c# for this hash how would you write it?

Answer (score 3):

Please see my answer to another Stack Overflow question which is similar, here:

[Need a smaller alternative to GUID for DB ID but still unique and random for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529647/need-a-smaller-alternative-to-guid-for-db-id-but-still-unique-and-random-for-url/529852#529852)

I posted a C# class called "ShortCodes", that does exactly what you're looking for,  i.e. generate a unique baseX (where X is anything you like!) hash based upon a integer/long number, and also to convert back again.

I actually wrote this little class precisely to mimic the short code/hash generation of sites like TinyUrl.com and Bit.ly for my own purposes.

I can't say if this is the absolute *fastest* way of achieving this, but it's not exactly slow either!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Eric Lippert suggested [lookup tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838097/fastest-way-to-enumerate-through-turned-on-bits-of-an-integer/838442#838442) in a similar earlier question. His answer is perfect for your purposes as well.