# Cast int as byte array in C++

Tags: c++, casting, byte, segmentation-fault

I am trying to use implement the LSB lookup method suggested by Andrew Grant in an answer to this question: [Position of least significant bit that is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set)

However, it's resulting in a segmentation fault. Here is a small program demonstrating the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned char Byte;

int main()  
{  
    int value = 300;  
    Byte* byteArray = (Byte*)value;  
    if (byteArray[0] > 0)  
    {  
        std::cout<< "This line is never reached. Trying to access the array index results in a seg-fault." << std::endl;  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
I've read that it's not good practice to use 'C-Style' casts in C++. Should I use `reinterpret_cast<Byte*>(value)` instead? This still results in a segmentation fault, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this:

```
(Byte*) &value;
```

You don't want a pointer to address 300, you want a pointer to where 300 is stored. So, you use the address-of operator `&` to get the address of `value`.

Comment: Fixes his pointer problem, but the cast is still unnecessary with the given problem.

Answer (score 9):

While Erik answered your overall question, as a followup I would say emphatically -- yes, `reinterpret_cast` should be used rather than a C-style cast.

```
Byte* byteArray = reinterpret_cast<Byte*>(&value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The line should be:
Byte* byteArray = (Byte*)&value;

You should not have to put the (void *) in front of it.

-Chert

Answer (score 0):

```
char *array=(char*)(void*)&value;
```

Basically you take a pointer to the beginning of the string and recast it to a pointer to a byte.

Answer (score 0):

@Erik already fixed your primary problem, but there is a subtle one that you still have.  If you are only looking for the least significant **bit**, there is no need to bother with the cast at all.

```
int main()
{
    int value = 300;       
    if (value & 0x00000001)       
    {           
        std::cout<< "LSB is set" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He's looking for *position* of the least significant *set* bit. Which, obviously, can still be found without any byte array.

Comment: In that case, his implementation is entirely wrong.  What he has now will only check to see if the lowest byte is equal to 1.

Comment: Yep, but as he states, the code is a demo of a specific problem. My answer addresses that specific problem. If it's his real code, then it needs some work :P

Comment: Yes -- Sorry for the confusion. The code I posted is just a demonstration of the crash. The actual code is using a byte array in a similar way, but with a lot of other things going on.

Comment: No problem, but in either case, there is no need for a cast to to a byte to find the least significant set bit in an integer.  In fact, doing the cast would actually make it more complicated.