# netmask conversion to CIDR format in C++

Tags: c++, networking

I have to convert 2 DWORDs, IP address and a network mask to CDIR format...
So I have 2 DWORDs corresponding 1.1.1.1 and 255.255.255.255 and I want to come up with string
1.1.1.1/32

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not CDIR but CIDR: Classless Inter-Domain Routing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are a small and fixed number of valid netmasks (32, to be exact), the fastest way is probably to just build a map of masks to prefix length once at init time, and the conversion is just a lookup in the map.

Comment: I think this is the simplest approach due to the fixed size.

Answer (score 7):

Simplest approach:

```
  static unsigned short toCidr(char* ipAddress)
  {
      unsigned short netmask_cidr;
      int ipbytes[4];

      netmask_cidr=0;
      sscanf(ipAddress, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &ipbytes[0], &ipbytes[1], &ipbytes[2], &ipbytes[3]);

      for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
      {
          switch(ipbytes[i])
          {
              case 0x80:
                  netmask_cidr+=1;
                  break;

              case 0xC0:
                  netmask_cidr+=2;
                  break;

              case 0xE0:
                  netmask_cidr+=3;
                  break;

              case 0xF0:
                  netmask_cidr+=4;
                  break;

              case 0xF8:
                  netmask_cidr+=5;
                  break;

              case 0xFC:
                  netmask_cidr+=6;
                  break;

              case 0xFE:
                  netmask_cidr+=7;
                  break;

              case 0xFF:
                  netmask_cidr+=8;
                  break;

              default:
                  return netmask_cidr;
                  break;
          }
      }

      return netmask_cidr;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The prefix-length is equal to the number of (leading) ones in the binary representation of the subnet mask.  So you just need to count the number of (leading) ones.

Comment: Or the number of [trailing zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set)

Answer (score 3):

Not efficient if you have a large amount of these to do, as it goes through the bits one at a time.  But very straightforward way to count each bit in the netmask:

```
int cidr = 0;
while ( netmask )
{
    cidr += ( netmask & 0x01 );
    netmask >>= 1;
}
```

Then combine the IP address with this CIDR value.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't completely portable, but is likely the fastest way of doing this if your program is running on a chip that supports the Intel instruction set. (And a similar approach may work for other architectures). The Intel chips have an instruction called `POPCNT`, which returns the number of bits in a variable that are set to `1`. Most compilers should provide an intrinsic to access this. For example, the Microsoft compilers give you `__popcnt` and GCC gives you `__builtin_popcount`. (With various flavors for different argument sizes).

Assuming a well-formed mask (as do all of the other solutions offered here), you can get the CIDR bit count with a single machine instruction.

```
inline uint32_t getBitCountFromIPv4Mask(uint32_t mask) {
    return __builtin_popcount(mask);    // presumes a well-formed mask.
}
```

You can do this with IPv6 masks as well. There's a 64-bit version of `POPCNT`, but since `in6_addr` won't give out address fragments in 64 bit chunks, it's probably best to not use it here.

```
uint32_t getBitCountFromIPv6Mask(const in6_addr &mask) {
    uint32_t bitCount = 0;

    for (uint32_t ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++) {
        bitCount += __builtin_popcount(mask.s6_addr32[ii]);
    }

    return bitCount;
}
```