# How to clear the most significant bit?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

How do I change the most significant bit in an int from 1 to 0? For instance, I want to change 01101 to 0101.

Comment: what do you mean by "first 1 on 0"?

Comment: perform logical and operation like 01101 & 01101 = 01101

Comment: I believe the question is: "Traverse through the integer bit by bit. The first time you encounter a 1, change it to a zero. Leave everything else unchanged."

Comment: What is the type of your "bit-container"? int, long, string... ?

Answer (score 11):

**Edit: Simplified (and explained) answer**

The answer I gave below is overkill if your *only* goal is to set the most significant bit to zero.

That final bit of code constructs a bit mask that includes all the bits in the number.

```
mask |= mask >> 1;
mask |= mask >> 2;
mask |= mask >> 4;
mask |= mask >> 8;
mask |= mask >> 16;
```

Here is the series of calculations it performs on a given 32 bit unsigned integer:

```
mask = originalValue
mask:               01000000000000000000000000000000
mask |= mask >> 1:  01100000000000000000000000000000
mask |= mask >> 2:  01111000000000000000000000000000
mask |= mask >> 4:  01111111100000000000000000000000
mask |= mask >> 8:  01111111111111111000000000000000
mask |= mask >> 16: 01111111111111111111111111111111
```

Since it does a bit-shift right, which does no wrap around, it will never set bits higher than the most significant bit to one.  Since it is using a logical `or`, you will never explicitly set any values to zero that weren't already zero.

Logically, this will always create a bit mask that fills the whole `uint`, up to and including the most significant bit that was originally set, but no higher.

From that mask it is fairly easy to shrink it to include all *but* the most significant bit that was originally set:

```
mask = mask >> 1: 00111111111111111111111111111111
```

Then just do a logical `and` against the original value, and it will set all the most significant bits in the number to zero, up to and including the most significant bit from the original value:

```
originalValue &= mask: 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

The original number I used here shows the mask-building process well, but it doesn't show that last calculation very well.  Lets run through the calculations with some more interesting example values (the ones in the question):

```
originalValue: 1101
mask = originalValue
mask:               00000000000000000000000000001101
mask |= mask >> 1:  00000000000000000000000000001111
mask |= mask >> 2:  00000000000000000000000000001111
mask |= mask >> 4:  00000000000000000000000000001111
mask |= mask >> 8:  00000000000000000000000000001111
mask |= mask >> 16: 00000000000000000000000000001111
mask = mask >> 1:   00000000000000000000000000000111
```

And here is the value you're looking for:

```
originalValue &= mask: 00000000000000000000000000000101
```

Since we can see this works, lets put the final code together:

```
uint SetHighestBitToZero(uint originalValue)
{
    uint mask = originalValue;

    mask |= mask >> 1;
    mask |= mask >> 2;
    mask |= mask >> 4;
    mask |= mask >> 8;
    mask |= mask >> 16;

    mask = mask >> 1;

    return originalValue & mask;
}

// ...
Console.WriteLine(SetHighestBitToZero(13)); // 1101
```

> 5

(which is 0101)

**Original answer I gave**

For these kind of questions, I often reference this article:

["Bit Twiddling Hacks"](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

The particular section you want is called "Finding integer log base 2 of an integer (aka the position of the highest bit set)".

Here is the first of a series of solutions (each more optimal than the previous):

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious

The final solution in the article is (converted to C#):

```
uint originalValue = 13;
uint v = originalValue; // find the log base 2 of 32-bit v
int r;  // result goes here

uint[] MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition = 
{
  0, 9, 1, 10, 13, 21, 2, 29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30,
  8, 12, 20, 28, 15, 17, 24, 7, 19, 27, 23, 6, 26, 5, 4, 31
};

v |= v >> 1; // first round down to one less than a power of 2 
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;

r = (int)MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[(uint)(v * 0x07C4ACDDU) >> 27];
```

Once you've found the highest set bit, simply mask it out:

```
originalValue &= ~(uint)(1 << r); // Force bit "r" to be zero
```

Comment: This looks very much like the book 'Hackers Delight'

Comment: @luketorjussen: Thanks for the plug! I'll check that book out :)

Comment: Has anyone checked that function?

Comment: @L.B: I haven't, but supposedly that site has.  There are 3 or 4 more variants on that site if you don't like the one in the answer.  After some googling I found this answer which looks like it links to articles describing the algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set/757266#757266

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham, I don't want to argue about algorithm. What I wanted to say was, your code doesn't do what is asked in the question. Please check your code and then see my simplified answer

Comment: I have to downvote since copy-paste is not always a solution.

Comment: @L.B.: The original code, the part I copy-pasted, is correct (tho needs to be converted to C# to compile).  The part I added at the end (`v &= ~(1 << r);` was wrong and causing the error, due to signed/unsigned issues, and the fact that `v` gets changed in the middle of the function.  See my edit for a corrected answer.  I have hand verified that it gives the correct answer in the case of the OP, and you can read the article to see why it is correct mathematically =P

Comment: @L.B.: Okay, I've gotten out of copy-paste mode, and fixed my answer :)  But that article is still a great resource, so I've left that part in

Answer (score 3):

Inspired from Merlyn Morgan-Graham's answer

```
static uint fxn(uint v)
{
    uint i = v;

    v |= v >> 1; 
    v |= v >> 2;
    v |= v >> 4;
    v |= v >> 8;
    v |= v >> 16;

    return (v >> 1) & i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the following (untested):

```
int a = 13; //01101
int value = 0x80000000;
while ((a & value) != value)
{
  value = value >> 1;
}
if (value > 0)
  a = a ^ value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 0xD; //01101
int wk = x;
int mask = 1;
while(0!=(wk >>= 1)) mask <<= 1;
x ^= mask; //00101
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the type, you can shift out the bits.
You could also just as easily put it in a BitArray and flip the MSB.

Example 1:

```
short value = -5334;
var ary = new BitArray(new[] { (value & 0xFF00) >> 8 });
ary.Set(7, false);
```

Example 2:

```
short value = -5334;
var newValue = Convert.ToInt16((value << 1) >> 1);

// Or

newValue = Convert.ToUInt16(value);
```

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way to do bitwise operations like this is to use the left shift operator (<<).

`(1 << 3) = 100b`, `(1 << 5) = 10000b` etc.

then you use a value in which you want to change a certain bit and use 
| (OR) if you want to change it to a 1 or 
& ~ (AND NOT) if you want to change it to a 0.

Like this:

```
int a = 13; //01101
int result = a | (1 << 5); //gives 11101
int result2 = result & ~(1 << 5); //gives 01101
```

Comment: `(1 << 3) = 8, (1 << 5) = 32`

Comment: @ L.B. they are binary values

Comment: They weren't while I was writing comment

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem the OP asked for, since `a = 13` is just an example (the OP said "for instance"). It is clear that what the OP wants is a solution that works for an arbitrary integer.

Answer (score -3):

If you will take that as integet then the code the result will always be displayed without having the zero.may be string manipulation will out put something you want but not sure how that is going to help you. Using string that will be something like below:

```
  string y = "01101";
  int pos = y.IndexOf("1");
  y = y.Insert(pos, "0");
  y = y.Remove(pos + 1, 1);
```

Comment: The question is clearly tagged `bit-manipulation` so it is clear that what the OP wants is speed. Although the result from your answer is correct, doing so by converting from `int` to `string` destroys the original purpose of the question.