# Is there a standard equation of form y=f(x) i.e. explicit function representing below given input output pair?

Tags: math

```
X   Y
-------
1   1
2   1
3   3
4   1
5   3
6   5
7   7
8   1
9   3
10  5
11  7
12  9
13  11
14  13
15  15
16  1
17  3
18  5
19  7
20  9
21  11
22  13
23  15
24  17
25  19
26  21
27  23
28  25
29  27
30  29
31  31
32  1
33  3
34  5
```

I tried representing the pattern in form of line graph.

[image: Line Graph for the input output pairs]

The pattern is like this,

if n is of the form 2^N then f(n) = 1
else f(n) = f(n-1)+2

Also, use f(1) = 1 as base condition (already covered by above logic)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to [Math SO](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In what language? You can always write that function yourself

Comment: *"if n is of the form 2^n then f(n) = 1"* <<<< Nonononononono. Big no. I strongly, very strongly advise you not to use the same variable name for two different numbers. You could say "if x is of the form 2^n, then f(x) = 1" or "if n is of the form 2^k, then f(n) = 1" but DO NOT say "if n is of the form 2^n, then f(n) = 1" otherwise it's going to be impossible to reason about this. You're going to have to write n = 2^n and nothing is going to make sense.

Comment: This looks like a [Josephus permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's "clear the most significant bit, multiply by 2, and add 1".  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790233/how-to-clear-the-most-significant-bit could give you a start with the first step.  It's simpler if your language has a function like "count leading zeros" or other integer log base 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the recurrence formula `f(n) = f(n-1) + 2` you can deduce that if n is of the form `2^k + j` where `j < 2^k`, then: `f(2^k + j) = f(2^k) + 2 * j`.

And since you also know that `f(2^k) = 1`, you can conclude:

```
f(2^k + j) = 1 + 2 * j
```

Now if you want a formula for `f(n)`, all you have to do is write `j` as a function of `n`. There is no particularly pretty way to write this formula, here is one:
`j = n - 2^⌊log2(n)⌋`
And hence:

```
f(n) = 1 + 2 * (n - 2^⌊log2(n)⌋)
```

where ⌊ ⌋ denotes the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) and log2 denotes the [binary logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm).