# finding the first set bit in a binary number

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I need to find the first set bit in a binary number from  right to left; I came up with this solution:

```
int cnt=0;
while (number& 1 ==0)
{
    cnt++;
    number>>=1;
}
```

Is there  a better way of doing it? Some clever bit manipulation technique?

Comment: That will find you the first set bit, from right to left. Which do you want?

Comment: I corrected the question; thanks!

Comment: I don't currently have the time to make this into an answer, but you can use [these](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightParallel) from bit twiddling hacks to count consecutive zeros on the right (and so, first bit set)

Comment: "better" in what way? Readability/Maintainability, code size, binary size, performance? In case of performance, do you have additional information on the expected input (e.g. probability distribution)?

Comment: Beware the lure of cleverness; many a great mind has been lost to its call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to be fast, bitscan instruction (`bsf`, `bsr`) or [bit-twiddling hack](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) is the target to go.

**EDIT: 
The idea of using switch-case table to improve performance is nothing but immature.**

Comment: mmmmmh. 8 = 0x08 gives 0x08 - (0x08 & 0x07) = 0x08 - 0 = 0x08; 10 = 0x0a gives 0x0a - (0x0a & 0x09) = 0x0a - 0x08 = 0x02. So it seems that the first bit set remains. (This is not a proof). I think the code is a bit obscure and needs a proof as a comment. But it would be quite fast. But the mentioned switch(){...} will have 32 or 64 powers of two as the different cases (which makes it quite large).

Comment: @Ronald  The first set bit of `number` will be the only set bit of `t`, so you only need 32 or 64 cases in the switch.

Comment: Yep, that's what I stated: 32 or 64 powers of two. But in my opinion that is a quite lengthy switch. Depending on the effective machine code executed for evaluating the switch statement, it might even eat the performance you saved by the elegant way of leaving only the first bit set.

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend replacing an idiomatic readable loop with an obscure calculation followed by a 32- or 64-way switch, unless it's a) well documented, and b) proven to have a substantial and necessary impact on performance.

Comment: @Ronald  If you really want it to be fast, bitscan instruction (`bsf`, `bsr`) is the target to go.

Comment: Why so complicated? You could do `number & -number` right? Or is there some obscure standard-based objection to that?

Comment: @Ronald  I realized that switch-case is not a good idea for this problem.  Either bitscan instruction or bittwiddle hack is better.  The method in the original post isn't that bad either (with bug fixed of course).

Comment: @neverhoodboy: actually we're discussing quite a lot in order to improve some code that does 32 (or 64) iterations and perfectly fits into a processor's first level cache ;-) So I regard this all more from the academic point of view.

Comment: @Ronald  I'm new to SO, so I'm not sure if it's ok for me to delete this post.  I don't want this immature answer to confuse anyone.  The other answers made by Jarod42 and herohuyongtao are much better.

Answer (score 12):

processor may have instruction to find that directly:

**Windows/MSVC:**

- [_BitScanForward()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfd9z0bb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [_BitScanReverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**GCC:**

- [__builtin_ffs()](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)
- [__builtin_ctz()](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)
- [__builtin_clz()](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)

These typically map directly to native hardware instructions. So it doesn't get much faster than these.

But since there's no C/C++ functionality for them, they're only accessible via compiler intrinsics.

You can do it manually that way:

`n & (n - 1)` is a technique to remove the rightmost set bit.

So, `n - (n & n - 1)` will return a number with only the rightmost set bit.

then a 'log2' of the result give the solution: [this link may help](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious)

You may alternatively use a switch case with all `1 << k` will give you the solution

```
switch (n - (n & n - 1)) {
    case 0: ...
    case 1 << 0: return 0;
    case 1 << 1: return 1;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your Answer is clearer than neverhoodboy's answer, but basically the same. Do you happen to know how the switch statement is evaluated (on machine code level)? It might turn out to be only as fast or even slower as the original solution (which had to be improved).

Comment: @Ronald: I originally post this answer to explain neverhoodboy's one. I found some duplicate on SO, I will try to find the better manual technique now.

Comment: I was quite happy with your answer, because I didn't know the trick `n & (n - 1)`. Anyway, the fastest portable way will probably be something like: test bytewise first and as soon as you get a hit, test the byte for set bits. That would reduce the number of operations from (on average) 32 * (if + add + shift) to 2 * if + 4 * (if + add + shift). So effectively an improvement of factor almost 8.

Answer (score 5):

[Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) offers an excellent collection of, er, bit twiddling hacks, with performance/optimisation discussion attached. For your problem (from that site), you can use multiply-and-lookup strategy:

```
unsigned int c = number;  // your input number
int r;           // result goes here
static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};
r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((uint32_t)((c & -c) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
```

Comment: Assuming 32 bit int this is the proper answer.

Comment: @Xarn Another assumption is 2's complement representation?

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
int cnt=0;
   while (number& 1 ==0)
   {
       cnt++;
       number>>=1;
   }
```

has a bug. For example if number is equal to 0 then the loop will be infinite.

I would rewrite it the following way

```
int cnt = 0;
if ( number ) while ( !( number & ( 1 << cnt++ ) ) );
```

In this case if number is not equal to 0 then the position (cnt) of the set bit will be count starting from 1. Otherwise the position will be equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the accepted answer is right. I just tested the naive loop versus the (num & -num) solution. They are both the same speed. The naive loop is much less code. I built with:

gcc 4.7.2 from MinGW, on Win 7
gcc test.c -o test.exe -std=c99 -Wall -O2

Here's my code (it probably has some corner case bugs, but I suspect the timings are roughly valid).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_NUMS 65536


int find_first_bits(unsigned nums[NUM_NUMS])
{
    int total = 0; // Prevent compiler from optimizing out the code
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NUMS; i++) {
            switch (nums[i] & -nums[i]) {
                case (1<<0): total += 1; break;
                case (1<<1): total += 2; break;
                case (1<<2): total += 3; break;
                case (1<<3): total += 4; break;
                case (1<<4): total += 5; break;
                case (1<<5): total += 6; break;
                case (1<<6): total += 7; break;
                case (1<<7): total += 8; break;
                case (1<<8): total += 9; break;
                case (1<<9): total += 10; break;
                case (1<<10): total += 11; break;
                case (1<<11): total += 12; break;
                case (1<<12): total += 13; break;
                case (1<<13): total += 14; break;
                case (1<<14): total += 15; break;
                case (1<<15): total += 16; break;
                case (1<<16): total += 17; break;
                case (1<<17): total += 18; break;
                case (1<<18): total += 19; break;
                case (1<<19): total += 20; break;
                case (1<<20): total += 21; break;
                case (1<<21): total += 22; break;
                case (1<<22): total += 23; break;
                case (1<<23): total += 24; break;
                case (1<<24): total += 25; break;
                case (1<<25): total += 26; break;
                case (1<<26): total += 27; break;
                case (1<<27): total += 28; break;
                case (1<<28): total += 29; break;
                case (1<<29): total += 30; break;
                case (1<<30): total += 31; break;
                case (1<<31): total += 32; break;
            }
        }
    }

    return total;
}


int find_first_bits2(unsigned nums[NUM_NUMS])
{
    int total = 0; // Prevent compiler from optimizing out the code
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NUMS; i++) {
            unsigned mask = 1;
            for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= 32; cnt++, mask <<= 1) {
                if (nums[i] & mask) {
                    total += cnt;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return total;
}


int main() {
    // Create some random data to test
    unsigned nums[NUM_NUMS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NUMS; i++) {
        nums[i] = rand() + (rand() << 15);
    }

    clock_t start_time, end_time;
    int result;

    start_time = clock();
    result = find_first_bits(nums);
    end_time = clock();
    printf("Time = %.5f, result = %d\n", (end_time - start_time) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC), result);

    start_time = clock();
    result = find_first_bits2(nums);
    end_time = clock();
    printf("Time = %.5f, result = %d\n", (end_time - start_time) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC), result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the action to test.  I realized the issue as I wrote in the comments under my post.  Actually I was thinking of deleting my answer so as no to confuse anyone......

Comment: Could you add test for the solution from everyone's favourite collection of bit hacks? http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html (see herohuyongtao's answer below)

Comment: @Xam: I will do this evening. I'm at work now :-(

Comment: The DeBruijn multiply yields a solution 60% faster than the naive loop. It takes approximately 11 cycles per number processed.

Comment: 3x faster than the DeBruijin method is Andrew Grant's lookup table method from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set