# log2 of an integer that is a power of 2

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, logarithm

Is there an efficient way to find the log2 of a number assuming it's a power of 2. I know the obvious ways like having a table or

```
for (log2=0;x!=1;x>>=1,log2++);
```

But I am wondering if there is a more efficient/elegant way.

Comment: Did you check math libraries? I bet there are some efficient functions

Comment: What about log2(x) where x is the number for which you want to find the log of 2 ?

Comment: http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_19.html

Comment: but then you probably really just want `std::log2()` from `<cmath>`. Then only worry about trying to find a more efficient one if you can demonstrate a bottleneck using a profiler.

Comment: Assuming `x` is a power of 2, you can immediately improve the worst-case running time using a binary search. Given the book-keeping overhead for right-shift / masking, this may not be much of an improvement. If the distribution for `x` is random, you should proceed from the most significant bit.

Comment: Use a table; given 64 bit integers there are only 64 of of them.

Comment: @RichardCritten - but how do you index that look-up table?

Comment: The `for` loop looks reasonable enough that a decent optimizer might recognize it. Have you checked whether your compiler actually generates a loop?

Comment: @BrettHale: You don't; binary search it, and then take the offset of the entry you found (!).

Comment: another duplicate: [Fastest way of computing the power that a “power of 2” number used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21438631/995714)

Comment: Actually, I'm interested in whether `std::log2()` might already use an optimised path in this case, though not interested enough to look it up personally right now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just count the number of leading or trailing zero bits, because any exact power-of-two is represented as a single 1 bit, with all other bits 0. Many CPUs have special instructions for doing this, and compilers such as gcc have intrinsics for these operations, which get compiled to a single instruction on appropriate architectures.

If you have an efficient `clz` ("count leading zeroes") then a `log2` implementation might look like this:

```
int32_t ilog2(uint32_t x)
{
    return sizeof(uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT - clz(x) - 1;
}
```

(Note: returns -1 for `ilog2(0)`.)

When using gcc or a gcc-compatible compiler you can just define `clz` like this:

```
#define clz(x) __builtin_clz(x)
```

Microsoft has something similar: [BitScanReverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd.aspx).

Note that it might appear more convenient to count *trailing* zeroes (using a `ctz` instruction), but [a `clz` instruction is more widely available on different CPU architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Hardware_support).

A further bonus of using `clz` rather than `ctz` is that you get `floor(log2(x))` for non-power-of-2 values, making your `ilog2` function more generally useful than if you had used `ctz`, which only works for exact powers-of-2.

See also: [Finding the first set bit in a binary number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21624122/253056).

Comment: Isn't only ctz(num) sufficient  to get the trailing zeros in the num ?

Comment: __builtin_ctz is a more straightforward option, surely...

Comment: Yes, not all CPUs have a `ctz` instruction though (e.g. ARM) - `clz` seems to be more common, in my experience. See: [Find first set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) Wikipedia entry for a good summary.

Comment: Also see newly added note above re log2 for non-power-of-2 integer arguments.

Comment: Since most people will be using Intel/AMD, the assembler mnemonics are ``bsr`` rsp. ``bsf``. By the way, I remember that they were fairly slow anyhow when they were introduced (probably implemented as a microassembler loop).

Comment: For ctz, I didn't check arm, but on aarch64 gcc generates rbit+clz, which shouldn't be much worse than 31-clz.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: fair enough - although you might still want to add handling for the 0 case (if needed), which you get for free when using `clz`.

Comment: (0 is not a power of 2, but indeed people often need to handle power-of-2 or 0) gcc's doc says that __builtin_c[lt]z are both undefined with an argument of 0.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't benchmarked this, but it ought to run reasonably fast since it doesn't require many iterations:

```
int which_power_of_2(uint64_t x) {
    uint64_t z = 0x0000000100000000ULL;
    int p = 31, d = 16;
    while (d) {
        if (x & (z-1)) {
            p -= d;
            z >>= d;
        }
        else {
            p += d;
            z <<= d;
        }
        d >>= 1;
    }
    return x ? ((x & z) ? p+1 : p) : -1;
}
```