# Efficient Division by Least Significant Bit set in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, performance, integer, bit-manipulation

I would like to perform the following operation as quickly as possible

```
x / LSB(x)
```

where `x` is an integral value unknown at compile time and `LSB(x) = x & -x`.
(Alternatively, the operation is equivalent to an *even* division by the highest power of 2 <= x.) I am looking for a *reasonably* portable solution (without compiler intrinsics/builtins like GCC's `__builtin_clz` or alike).

My concern is that the following simple implementation

```
x / (x & -x)
```

would still result in an expensive division as compiler might fail to realize that the division is in fact equivalent to right-shift by the number of trailing zeroes in the divisor.

If my concerns are reasonable, what would be a more efficient way to implement it?

I would appreciate a solution that is easily extendible to integral types of sizes 32-bit, 64-bits, 128-bits, ...

Comment: As far as I know you can't really do that yet, well except with a bunch of preprocessor stuff to select the right intrinsic. [N3864](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3864.html) would help..

Comment: Are you coding in C or C++? Also, compilers are usually pretty good at spotting this stuff.

Comment: C++. I mostly care about GCC, clang and MSVC++.

Comment: What do you mean by even division? I don't see how a division by the highest power of 2 <= x can be equivalent to x / (x & -x).

Comment: Even division = division without remainder.

Comment: @FalkHüffner: Who said "highest power of 2 <= x"?  This is the least significant set bit, not the most significant.  Division by the MSB would always yield `1`.  Oh, now I see that in the question.  Yes, the "alternate" explanation is clearly wrong.

Comment: If you divide by non-MSB (e.g. highest bit) you *do* have remainder, and thus it is not considered even division. I see no problem with the alternate explanation.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
x >>= ffs(x)-1;
```

The `ffs` function conforms to 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.

It won't work if `x` is 0.

Comment: something like `int _ffs = ffs(x); x >>= _ffs - !!_ffs;` should work for zero as well..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that neither BSD nor POSIX are C or C++.

Comment: FFS... couldn't they have given it a better name? aha

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on CLZ (count leading zeros) hardware instructions, you can count leading zeros as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set/757266#757266). It's very fast with a look-up and multiplication by a magic number. I'll re-post the code here:

```
unsigned x;  // input to clz
unsigned c;  // output of clz
static const unsigned MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};
c = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((unsigned)((x & -x) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
```

Once you have counted the leading zeros, you no loner need to use a division instruction. Instead, you can just shift the value right by `c`. That is (eliminating an unneeded temporary value), the code becomes this:

```
static const unsigned MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};

x >>= MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((unsigned)((x & -x) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27]; // x /= LSB(x)
```