# How to get the position of the first set bit of a number

Tags: c, math, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

for example, my definition looks like the following:

```
#define AA              0x0000000000000001LL
#define BB              0x0000000000000002LL
#define CC              0x0000000000000004LL
#define DD              0x0000000000000008LL
#define EE              0x0000000000000010LL
#define FF              0x0000000000000020LL
#define GG              0x0000000000000040LL
#define HH              0x0000000000000080LL
```

I would like to get the position of the first set bit (counting backwards from the least significant bit)  from the maximum definition.

```
h = getAmountFromBitwise(HH);
output of h is 8;
b = getAmountFromBitwise(BB);
output b is 2;
```

Is there any better way to implement getAmountFromBitwise()?

```
int getAmountFromBitwise(long long input) {
  2^x = input;
  y=x+1;
  return y;
}
```

Comment: Better than count it manually. :-D

Comment: what does `getAmountFromBitwise()` do now?

Comment: The definations are defined in sequence, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x8, 0x10, ...., every next value are multiple by 2 from previous one.

Comment: Are you saying that you want a function to identify the most-significant bit set in its argument?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Seems like the index of **L**SB, index starting at 1.

Comment: your function doesn't even compile because `2^x = input;` is invalid and x and y weren't declared before. And this is not the "amount" but the bit position

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, it is just my pseudo code. i want to know how do i get the y.

Comment: best way: `__builtin_ctz` in gcc and `_BitScanReverse` in MSVC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Wouldn't that be [`_BitScanForward`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wfd9z0bb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this as your `getAmountFromBitwise()`.

```
int highest_bit_set(long long n) {
  int result = 1;
  while(n >>= 1) /* keep shifting right until n == 0 */
    result++;
  return result;
}
```

Note that this requires that `n != 0` for a correct result.