# How to find n where k = 2^n

Tags: c++, c

If I know an integer `k = 2^n`, how can I efficiently find `n`?
In other words, if I know a single bit in a integer is set, how can I get the location of the bit?

An idea is to find the Hamming Weight of `k-1` but are there any other simpler ways I'm not thinking about?

Comment: Count the number of single-place right shifts before the value is 0.  There may be other techniques too — check out [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: I upvoted this because although the "duplicate" gives the answer you probably need, knowing in advance that it is a power of two might have changed the answer; not a bad question therefore imho. Also note that the answers given somehow are all different from what I use [...] (as hard-core coder): https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/log2.h

Answer (score 1):

[Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) have a lot of amazing (and obscure, performance oriented) bit hacks. The best one for your use seems using multiply and lookup.

```
unsigned int v;  // find the number of trailing zeros in 32-bit v 
int r;           // result goes here
static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};
r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((uint32_t)((v & -v) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
```

[This page](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/BitScan) provides a detailed analysis of the problem with a focus on chess programming.

Answer copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set).
PS: Didn't know how to give credit to the author on that question, and so wrote it like this.