# Gettin last non zero bit on the left

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have value 0b001010100 and I need position of least 1 in this value. 
Anyone has idea how to achieve it?
I need position from the left so for the leftest 1 I want to get 6.

Comment: There are more duplicates, if you don't like the answers there.

Comment: Here are more methods: [Position of least significant bit that is set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set/758056)