# The Inverse of a bit-shift to the left in the format 1 << n

Tags: java, bit-shift

Let's say I have the following bit masks:

```
1 << 1, // 2
1 << 2, // 4 
1 << 3, // 8 
1 << 4, // 16 
1 << 5, // 32 
1 << 6  // 64
```

I would like to get the 'inverse'.

This does the job:

```
void foo(int n) {
  int c = 1;
  while (n/2 >= 2) {
    n /= 2;  
    c++;;
  }
  println(c);
}
```

For example, `1 << 4` resulted in 16. If I run `foo(16)` it prints 4.
However, I feel like it could be done a lot simpler, but I can't figure out how.

Is it possible?

Comment: Logarithms my friend!

Comment: [Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros-int-) can be used to get the position of the 1 bit, and its javadoc even has a couple of useful formulae with logarithms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Position of least significant bit that is set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set)

Comment: @talex thanks, I would never have found that topic without knowing the terminology.

Answer (score 2):

`BigInteger` has many useful methods - including [getLowestSetBit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#getLowestSetBit%28%29). It probably does it as fast as it can possibly be done.

```
public void test() {
    System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(16).getLowestSetBit());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo(int n)
{
    println( (Math.log(n) / Math.log(2))); 
    //cast to int with (int) to take off decimal place
}
```

Returns the "inverse" bitshift as you are calling it, the base 2 logarithm.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but in the duplicate I saw a awesome technical post for  a really fast solution :)

Comment: Okay! Glad I could help :)

Comment: Can you provide an example in which it is not?

Comment: I can't. I just have strange filling when use floating point arithmetic for bit manipulation :)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly faster and not depend on value itself.

**UPDATED version**

```
private static int foo2(int value) {
    int result = 0;

    int mask = 0xFFFF;
    int shift = 1<<4;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        result <<= 1;
        if ((value & mask) == 0) {
            result |= 1;
            value >>>= shift;
        }
        shift >>>= 1;
        mask >>= shift;
    }
    return result;
}
```