# Find the index on 1 in binary number of zeros

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, decimal, bit

I have a set of binary numbers (originally was hex's) that I want to find the index of 1 in it. These sets are :

```
1000, index = 3
0100, index = 2
0010, index = 1
0001, index = 0
```

I can't wrap my head around it, I tried getting the decimal representation and do some math magic with it to turn it into 0, 1, 2, 3 but no clue.

Comment: "I have a set of binary numbers" Are the binary numbers strings? Or just integers? Also, why is the index for 1000 zero? Don't you count from the right?

Comment: @MOehm Edited. These numbers was 4 hex numbers. Also about the index that was a mistake, sorry, I'm counting from the right.

Comment: Count the number of times you can halve the (integer) number before it becomes 0.

Comment: As there are only four of them use a case statement

Comment: Could also be a duplicate of [Position of least significant bit that is set](http://stackoverflow.com/q/757059/335858)