# Simple way of getting the nth array element when all I have is n^2

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitmask

I have an array of nine elements and an integer.
Using the integer and bitmasking I want to save information about whether an element of the array is valid.

So my question is: Is there a simpler way than using log2() of math.h to get from my bitmask to my array element number? 
For example, I store `foo2,` `foo4` and `foo5` in `mValue` using bitmasking. 
Then I want to get the array element at position `foo2 = 2`, which is the second bit, so the 2nd array element, which is `34`.
But the only way I can think of is the `log2(n)` funtion.
Is there a simpler one using bitshifting maybe?

Simply put, I want to do this:

Is the nth bit of an integer `mValue` set to 1? then get me the nth element of an array `bar`.

```
#include <math.h>  

const int  foo1 = 1;
const int  foo2 = 2;
const int  foo3 = 4;
const int  foo4 = 8;
const int  foo5 = 16;

int bar[9] = {23,34,82,8,7,0,23,19,20};
int mValue;

void SetValue(int nVal)
{
 mValue = nVal; 
}

bool IsElementValid(int nVal)
{
 return mValue & nVal;
}

int main()
{
 SetValue(foo2 | foo4 | foo5 );
 IsElementValid(foo4); //true
 IsElementValid(foo5); //true
 IsElementValid(foo1); //false

 //access array element 1 with value foo2 (2)
 if(IsElementValid(foo2))
    printf("%d\n",     bar[log2(foo2)]); // output: '34'
}
```

Comment: [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set) might be useful for you

Answer (score 2):

The usual idiom is:

```
if (mValue & (1<<n)) {
  return bar[n];
}
```

EDIT: But if the only thing you have truly is `2^n` (and you cannot turn your logic around), you can still avoid the expensive (and double/float) call to `log2`:

```
int bit_pos=0;
unsigned int value = ...;   // your input

while (value>1) {
  value >>= 1;
  bit_pos++;
}
```

`bit_pos` now contains the position of the highest set bit in `value`; if `value=2^n`, it will be `n`.

I guess there are more elegant and/or even faster ways (I would not put it past Intel or other companies to create an assembler level command for this), but I would further optimize these things only if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! but this would onl work if I had `n`. But what I have is `2^n`.

Comment: When you have only nVal `2^n` (but why? It doesn't make any sense, usually it's quite easy to keep `n` around instead, or you will scan trough most of the bits in a loop, where again keeping index is easy): you can check if your compiler has bit count function, for example gcc has `int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)`, so then `n = __builtin_popcount (nVal-1);` @tzippy

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mValue & (1<<n)) {
  printf("%d\n", bar[n]);
}
```

I'm pretty new to bit twiddling but that just might work?