# Simple game algorithm checking if the move is valid

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array, dijkstra

I'm programming my first game and I have one last problem to solve. I need an algorithm to check if I can move a chosen ball to a chosen place.

Look at this picture:

[image]

The rule is, if I picked up the blue ball on the white background (in the very middle) I can move it to all the green spaces and I can't move it to the purple ones, cause they are sort of fenced by other balls. I naturally can't move it to the places taken by other balls. The ball can only move up, down, left and right.

Now I am aware that there is two already existing algorithms: A* and Dijkstra's algorithm that might be helpful, but they seem too complex for what I need (both using vectors or stuff that I weren't taught yet, I'm quite new to programming and this is my semester project). I don't need to find the shortest way, I just need to know whether the chosen destination place is fenced by other balls or not.

My board in the game is 9x9 array simply filled with '/' if it's an empty place or one of the 7 letters if it's taken.

**Is there a way I can code the algorithm in a simple way?**

---

*[I went for the flood fill and it works just fine, thank you for all your help and if someone has a similar problem - I recommend using flood fill, it's really simple and quick]*

Comment: depth first search or breadth first search will both work fine.

Comment: You are basically looking for the _flood fill algorithm_, google that. Even the most naive implementation of the algorithm will be good enough for a 9x9 grid.

Comment: Since you said that you weren't told what a vector is, this is most basic stuff. If you are really, REALLY in a hurry, skip it, but otherwise what you really should do is to read some basic tutorials. How is your field stored without vectors (or other STL containers)? In a raw array? Those will easily cause trouble for you in the future.

Comment: @Aziuth A square game board is one of the *very few* places where `std::vector` is distracting over `std::array`. I would recommend using `std::array<std::array<char, 9>, 9>` for *this* example. `char[9][9]` is too easy to confuse for a string.

Comment: @dtech: A question with relevant picture, prior research done into algorithms that are indeed technically correct but overkill for the limited input size? There are plenty of non-beginners still asking worse questions.

Comment: @Caleth That's why I wrote "(or other STL containers)". But yeah, `std::array` is the better fit. That said, in your example, I'd replace `char` by some enum class, since `char` has the intrinsic meaning of being a letter. Like `enum class Field : unsigned char {Empty, Green, Red, Blue};`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest using [Flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm:

> Flood fill, also called seed fill, is an algorithm that determines the
>   area connected to a given node in a multi-dimensional array. It is
>   used in the "bucket" fill tool of paint programs to fill connected,
>   similarly-colored areas with a different color, and in games such as
>   Go and Minesweeper for determining which pieces are cleared. When
>   applied on an image to fill a particular bounded area with color, it
>   is also known as boundary fill.

In terms of complexity time, this algorithm will be equals the recursive one: `O(N×M)`, where N and M are the dimensions of the input matrix. The key idea is that in both algorithms each node is processed at most once.

In this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flood-fill-algorithm-implement-fill-paint/) you can find a guide to the implementation of the algorithm.

More specifically, as Martin Bonner suggested, there are some key concepts for the implementation:

1. Mark all empty cells as unknown (all full cells are unreachable)
2. Add the source cell to a set of routable cells
3. While the set is not empty:

   - pop an element from the set;
   - mark all adjacent unknown cells as "reachable" and add them to the set
4. All remaining unknown cells are unreachable.

---

PS: You may want to read [Flood fill vs DFS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18490/flood-fill-vs-depth-first-search).

Comment: @Caleth, what "collection of cells"?

Comment: In your pseudocode "the set". `set`, `list`, `vector`, `array` are all class templates for "collection of ...", with differing specifics

Comment: I'm not the downvoter.  I didn't upvote until you added the pseudocode.

Comment: @Caleth: When I said "set",  I mean the mathematical object that can contain an element at most once.  The obvious implementation is `std::unordered_set<coordinate_pair>`.  If this is a performance bottleneck (on a larger, empty, board it might be), one could look at clever tricks with bitmaps and something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/21644413/771073 for the "pop front".

Answer (score 4):

You can do this very simply using the [**BFS(Breadth First Search)**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/) algorithm.

For this you need to study the **[Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type))**  *data structure*. Its pretty simple to implement, once you understand it.

**Key Idea**

Your cells will act as *vertices*, whereas the *edges* will tell whether or not you will be able to move from one  cell to another.

Once you have implemented you graph using an *adjacency list* or *adjacency matrix* representation, you are good to go and use the BFS algorithm to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I find it consfusing that you use `code formatting` for non code

Comment: @gsamaras I hope I am not complaining too much, just trying to give suggestions. Anyhow, `O(NxN)` obvisouly isnt code, but `vertices` and `edges` looks like it is refering to some specific type or variable name, when I understand it as refering to the abstract concept of vertices and edges that dont need special formatting

Comment: @gsamaras yeah i like both answers, and I do like the question. I find it quite interesting, because I never had the chance to try BFS or Flood Fill. I am curious to try it and both your answers will be a nice starting point. Unfortunately its not something I can do during working hours ;)

Comment: Hi Sumeet—in English the convention is to use either **bold** or *italics* when you're emphasizing something or defining a new term. (For instance: "A *dog* is a wolf-like animal with four legs.") It is never correct to use code formatting for something that's not code. I've fixed your post for you.

Comment: @wchargin Ok, will be careful in the future.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain as to why you did not like the answer.