# C - Get shift required from Bitmask

Tags: c, bitmask

I wonder if there is a nice way to get the shift that is required out of a bitmask applied to a variable without the need to define it.

Simple Example:

```
#define MASK  0xf0
#define SHIFT 4

uint8_t var = 0x20;
uint8_t wanted = (var & MASK) >> SHIFT;
```

How can I avoid using the SHIFT define but still get the same result?

Comment: Using `wanted = (var & MASK) >> 4;` of course. There is nothing magical about `#define`s.

Comment: Why is there an equal to sign in `#define`...!

Comment: @usr2564301: sure, but I want shift to be "generated" from the value in MASK

Comment: Unsure what you are asking. Do you want to find out `SHIFT` so that `(var & MASK) >> n == wanted` holds for some `wanted`?

Comment: @Ruks Edited, thx

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to ask...

Comment: @user3482407 Ah, so you want to find out `SHIFT` given only `MASK`, assuming `MASK` is a proper "mask". That means you are trying to find the lowest set bit in `MASK`, right?

Comment: @Acorn Exactly!

Comment: @user3482407 Then see [Position of least significant bit that is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set)

Comment: @user3482407 Then you have to know the value of `wanted` beforehand... and `>>=` over all possible combinations from 1 to n checking if they are equal your number along with the way...

Comment: @Acorn Thanks, but this is not really what I am looking for, I would prefer the additional defines instead of the whole function

Comment: @Ruks Can you clearify that? If I understand corret, this would mean that you shift through the whole variable in a loop and compare for "wanted", but what happens when var would be 0x02?

Comment: @user3482407 Oh, my mistake, I meant *0 to n*...

Comment: gcc was not tagged. But for it:  `(var & MASK) >> __builtin_ctz(MASK)`

Comment: Any reason why you can't do `#define GET_STUFF(x) ((x >> 4) & 0xFF)`?

Comment: @user3482407 Not sure what you mean: that question is precisely what you are looking for. There are many answers, and you can pick the solution that you prefer.

Comment: @SKi: This is awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You could do `uint8_t wanted = WANTED(var, mask);`, where `#define WANTED(var, mask) (((var) & (mask)) / ((mask) & ~((mask) - 1)))`.