# Most efficient way to find the bit with 0 in an array of uint32_t

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, bit-manipulation, hashtable

I am having an array of type `uint32_t` say of size 1024.

`int32_t *handle_generator= calloc(1024, sizeof(uint32_t));`

I am going to use this array `handle_generator` to generate handle for elements of certain type - `myType_t`.
When an element of `myType_t` is created, I have to find the first bit from the array `handle_generator` which is zero and return that index value. And I am going to use this value as handle for my newly created element.

The created element of type `myType_t` can be destroyed as well. In that case, the handle values of that destroyed element becomes free and can be reused. So the index in the array `handle_generator` (matching that handle value) should be set to 0.

After multiple creation and deletion of elements `myType_t` there will series of 0s and 1s bits in the array `handle_generator`.
In such a condition, what is the efficient way to find the first bit with value 0?

Simplest way is to loop through the array `handle_generator` by inspecting each bit, which would have a time complexity of 0(n); where n is the number of bits.

---

For example, after many additions and deletion, if the bits in the `handle_generator` array is as below

```
 0th                       13th
 |                         |
 v                         v
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|0|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|0|1|1|1|1|1|1|...|0|0|0|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If we have to find the first bit in the array - `handle_generator`, having value 0, then it is at index 13. So what is most efficient algorithm to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You have 1024 words to make a bit-mask of 32768 bits.

In addition to this, I would use 32 words to make a bit-mask indicating which of those 1024 words are full or non-full, and then a single word to make a bit mask of which of those 32 words are full.

That's only an additional 33 words, but with that you can find the first 0 very quickly -- use the top-level mask to find the first non-full mid-level mask, use the mid-level mask to find the first non-full word, and then find the first 0 in that word.

Of course, doing this quickly requires a quick way to find the index of the least significant bit that is set or cleared in a word.  That's a common topic: [Position of least significant bit that is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set)

Comment: Great. Thanks. This would bring the time complexity from O(n) to O(log n) with slight additional memory.