# Given an integer, how do I find the next largest power of two using bit-twiddling?

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

If I have a integer number `n`, how can I find the next number `k > n` such that `k = 2^i`, with some `i` element of `N` by bitwise shifting or logic.

Example: If I have `n = 123`, how can I find `k = 128`, which is a power of two, and not `124` which is only divisible by two. This should be simple, but it eludes me.

---

Related questions for some specific languages:

- C: *[Rounding up to next power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-up-to-next-power-of-2)*
- C++: *[Algorithm for finding the smallest power of two that's greater or equal to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364985/algorithm-for-finding-the-smallest-power-of-two-thats-greater-or-equal-to-a-giv)* (including C++20 `std::bit_ceil()`)

Comment: This would be a great interview question.

Comment: @Rick: I hope you are not an interviewer and I now put a poor applicant in a tight spot ;-)

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-off-to-nearest-power-of-2, anyway answers from this question could be of interest here too.

Comment: if n = 128, do you want to find k = 128, or k = 256?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm for finding the smallest power of two that's greater or equal to a given value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364985/algorithm-for-finding-the-smallest-power-of-two-thats-greater-or-equal-to-a-giv)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding up to next power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-up-to-next-power-of-2)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

For 32-bit integers, this is a simple and straightforward route:

```
unsigned int n;

n--;
n |= n >> 1;   // Divide by 2^k for consecutive doublings of k up to 32,
n |= n >> 2;   // and then or the results.
n |= n >> 4;
n |= n >> 8;
n |= n >> 16;
n++;           // The result is a number of 1 bits equal to the number
               // of bits in the original number, plus 1. That's the
               // next highest power of 2.
```

Here's a more concrete example. Let's take the number 221, which is 11011101 in binary:

```
n--;           // 1101 1101 --> 1101 1100
n |= n >> 1;   // 1101 1100 | 0110 1110 = 1111 1110
n |= n >> 2;   // 1111 1110 | 0011 1111 = 1111 1111
n |= n >> 4;   // ...
n |= n >> 8;
n |= n >> 16;  // 1111 1111 | 1111 1111 = 1111 1111
n++;           // 1111 1111 --> 1 0000 0000
```

There's one bit in the ninth position, which represents 2^8, or **256, which is indeed the next largest power of 2**. Each of the shifts overlaps all of the existing 1 bits in the number with some of the previously untouched zeroes, eventually producing a number of 1 bits equal to the number of bits in the original number. Adding one to that value produces a new power of 2.

Another example; we'll use 131, which is 10000011 in binary:

```
n--;           // 1000 0011 --> 1000 0010
n |= n >> 1;   // 1000 0010 | 0100 0001 = 1100 0011
n |= n >> 2;   // 1100 0011 | 0011 0000 = 1111 0011
n |= n >> 4;   // 1111 0011 | 0000 1111 = 1111 1111
n |= n >> 8;   // ... (At this point all bits are 1, so further bitwise-or
n |= n >> 16;  //      operations produce no effect.)
n++;           // 1111 1111 --> 1 0000 0000
```

And indeed, 256 is the next highest power of 2 from 131.

If the number of bits used to represent the integer is itself a power of 2, you can continue to extend this technique efficiently and indefinitely (for example, add a `n >> 32` line for 64-bit integers).

Comment: Ah great thanks! I had a hard time to understand why you could double k every step, but since you "double" every '1' it became obvious. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @AndreasT: No problem! (BTW, to see why you need to go all the way up to n >> 16, consider what happens if n is already a power of 2. You'll only have a single 1 bit that needs to cover all of the previous bits, which is why all the shifting is necessary.)

Comment: +1 yes, good trick, I like it :) Some more bit-twiddling tricks can be found here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: Great example, this algorithm appears in at least one place in the Java APIs and was confusing me.

Comment: Though this works but could anyone please give an explanation on why it works?

Comment: I think there is a typo in your second example, the number after the pipe should be 0100 0001.

Comment: Why not just bit shift until it equals zero? Seems like that would be faster.

Comment: @endolith That takes log N shifts. This takes log(log N) shifts, so it uses fewer shifts.

Comment: @JohnFeminella: Yeah, I probably should have read the code more carefully before commenting...

Comment: It does `k >= n`, not `k > n`

Comment: if you just add a n >> 32 line you'd get illegal instruction for values n > 4611686018427387904 , so for 64-bit you need a check whether n is beyond the largest power of two that actually fits in the 64-bit

Answer (score 31):

**Specifically on x86,** there is actually a assembly solution for this (since the 80386 instruction set).

You can use the BSR (Bit Scan Reverse) instruction to scan for the most significant bit in your integer.

> bsr scans the bits, starting at the
> most significant bit, in the
> doubleword operand or the second word.
> If the bits are all zero, ZF is
> cleared. Otherwise, ZF is set and the
> bit index of the first set bit found,
> while scanning in the reverse
> direction, is loaded into the
> destination register

(Extracted from: http://dlc.sun.com/pdf/802-1948/802-1948.pdf)

And than inc the result with 1.

so:

```
bsr ecx, eax  //eax = number
jz  @zero
mov eax, 2    // result set the second bit (instead of a inc ecx)
shl eax, ecx  // and move it ecx times to the left
ret           // result is in eax

@zero:
xor eax, eax
ret
```

In newer CPU's you can use the much faster `lzcnt` instruction (aka `rep bsr`). `lzcnt` does its job in a single cycle.

Comment: If your input is already a power of 2, this will not return it though

Comment: nitpick: The logic is correct, but the description of the `Z` flag is inverted: `jz` jumps when the `Z` flag is *set* - which is its state after testing a 0 value. (This goes all the way back to Intel's 8008 CPU.)

Answer (score 21):

A more mathematical way, without loops:

```
public static int ByLogs(int n)
{
    double y = Math.Floor(Math.Log(n, 2));

    return (int)Math.Pow(2, y + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I was searching for a "bit-twiddle" way. ;-)

Comment: +1, not what the OP wanted, but strangely enough I needed an answer that would fit in a single inline expression: `2 ^ (floor(log(x) / log(2)) + 1)`

Comment: What if the input is `0`?  Also, OP asked for the next largest power of 2, `floor` finds the next lower power of 2, no?

Comment: It gets you the existing value. The next part, y+1 gets you the next largest power.

Comment: @DanDan: but if n is already a power of 2, it gives the next power of 2 rather than returning n

Comment: @endolith: If `n` is a power of two and you want to obtain `n` instead of "the next power of two", you can use `2 ^ ( ceil(log(x) / log(2)) )` instead. But that was not the question (…how can I find the next number `k > n`…)

Comment: @Wauzl Yeah, but the log method is inaccurate for higher numbers anyway.  if x = 536870912 it returns 1073741824 instead of 536870912.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a logic answer:

```
function getK(int n)
{
  int k = 1;
  while (k < n)
    k *= 2;
  return k;
}
```

Comment: Ha, so simple! Didn't think about that one :)

Answer (score 8):

Here's John Feminella's answer implemented as a loop so it can handle [Python's long integers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric):

```py
def next_power_of_2(n):
    """
    Return next power of 2 greater than or equal to n
    """
    n -= 1 # greater than OR EQUAL TO n
    shift = 1
    while (n+1) & n: # n+1 is not a power of 2 yet
        n |= n >> shift
        shift <<= 1
    return n + 1
```

It also returns faster if n is already a power of 2.

For Python >2.7, this is simpler and faster for most N:

```py
def next_power_of_2(n):
    """
    Return next power of 2 greater than or equal to n
    """
    return 2**(n-1).bit_length()
```

[image]

Comment: If you're going to use bit shifts, you might as well do `shift <<= 1` instead of `shift *= 2`. Not sure if that's actually faster in Python, but it should be.

Answer (score 5):

*This answer is based on [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) to prevent any computing at runtime when the function parameter is passed as `const`*

### Greater than / Greater than or equal to

The following snippets are for the **next number k > n such that k = 2^i**
(n=123 => k=128, n=128 => k=256) as specified by OP.

If you want the **smallest power of 2 greater than OR equal to n** then just replace `__builtin_clzll(n)` by `__builtin_clzll(n-1)` in the following snippets.

### C++11 using GCC or Clang (64 bits)

```
#include <cstdint>  // uint64_t

constexpr uint64_t nextPowerOfTwo64 (uint64_t n)
{
    return 1ULL << (sizeof(uint64_t) * 8 - __builtin_clzll(n));
}
```

### Enhancement using [`CHAR_BIT`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) as proposed by [martinec](https://stackoverflow.com/u/2042871)

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr uint64_t nextPowerOfTwo64 (uint64_t n)
{
    return 1ULL << (sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT - __builtin_clzll(n));
}
```

### C++17 using GCC or Clang (from 8 to 128 bits)

```
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
constexpr T nextPowerOfTwo64 (T n)
{
   T clz = 0;
   if constexpr (sizeof(T) <= 32)
      clz = __builtin_clzl(n); // unsigned long
   else if (sizeof(T) <= 64)
      clz = __builtin_clzll(n); // unsigned long long
   else { // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40528716
      uint64_t hi = n >> 64;
      uint64_t lo = (hi == 0) ? n : -1ULL;
      clz = _lzcnt_u64(hi) + _lzcnt_u64(lo);
   }
   return T{1} << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T) - clz);
}
```

### Other compilers

If you use a compiler other than GCC or Clang, please visit the Wikipedia page listing the [**Count Leading Zeroes** bitwise functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Tool_and_library_support):

- Visual C++ 2005 => Replace `__builtin_clzl()` by `_BitScanForward()`
- Visual C++ 2008 => Replace `__builtin_clzl()` by `__lzcnt()`
- icc => Replace `__builtin_clzl()` by `_bit_scan_forward`
- GHC (Haskell) => Replace `__builtin_clzl()` by `countLeadingZeros()`

### Contribution welcome

Please propose improvements within the comments. Also propose alternative for the compiler you use, or your programming language...

### See also similar answers

- [nulleight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39944307/938111)
- [ydroneaud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10143264/938111)

Comment: By definition `uint64_t` (if it exists) has 64 data bits and no padding bits, therefore `sizeof(uint64_t)*CHAR_BIT` must be 64. Perhaps you were thinking of `long long` or `uint_fast64_t`?

Comment: Hi @MartinKealey I do not remember what I was thinking in 2017. Yes we may replace `sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT` by 64. Maybe I was thinking that `sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT` has a better meaning… What would you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a wild one that has no loops, but uses an intermediate float.

```
//  compute k = nextpowerof2(n)

if (n > 1) 
{
  float f = (float) n;
  unsigned int const t = 1U << ((*(unsigned int *)&f >> 23) - 0x7f);
  k = t << (t < n);
}
else k = 1;
```

This, and many other bit-twiddling hacks, including the on submitted by John Feminella, can be found [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2Float).

Comment: wtf! 8-)  , will check it out. Thx

Answer (score 2):

assume x is not negative.

```
int pot = Integer.highestOneBit(x);
if (pot != x) {
    pot *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use GCC, MinGW or Clang:

```
template <typename T>
T nextPow2(T in)
{
  return (in & (T)(in - 1)) ? (1U << (sizeof(T) * 8 - __builtin_clz(in))) : in;
}
```

If you use Microsoft Visual C++, use function `_BitScanForward()` to replace `__builtin_clz()`.

Comment: See also similar answer in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10143264/938111 (answered by [ydroneaud](http://stackoverflow.com/users/611560/ydroneaud) on 2012). See Wikipedia builtin bitwise functions for other compilers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Tool_and_library_support                 This a C++ 64-bits version:        `constexpr uint64_t nextPowerOfTwo64 (uint64_t x) { return 1ULL << (sizeof(uint64_t) * 8 - __builtin_clzll(x)); }`

Answer (score 1):

```
function Pow2Thing(int n)
{
    x = 1;
    while (n>0)
    {
        n/=2;
        x*=2;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit-twiddling, you say?

```
long int pow_2_ceil(long int t) {
    if (t == 0) return 1;
    if (t != (t & -t)) {
        do {
            t -= t & -t;
        } while (t != (t & -t));
        t <<= 1;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Each loop strips the least-significant 1-bit directly.  N.B. This only works where signed numbers are encoded in two's complement.

Comment: You can safely replace your `while` with `do/while` and save one test, as you've already confirmed the initial test with the preceding `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks @seh; improved with `do while`.

Comment: Fastest method here, why no upvotes? Although, I changed to `while(t > (t & -t))`.

Comment: @primo At least in C# the accepted answer is over 2.5 times faster on average for 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
int pot = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++, pot <<= 1)
    if (pot >= x)
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the most significant bit and shift it left once.  Here's a Python implementation.  I think x86 has an instruction to get the MSB, but here I'm implementing it all in straight Python.  Once you have the MSB it's easy.

```
>>> def msb(n):
...     result = -1
...     index = 0
...     while n:
...         bit = 1 << index
...         if bit & n:
...             result = index
...             n &= ~bit
...         index += 1
...     return result
...
>>> def next_pow(n):
...     return 1 << (msb(n) + 1)
...
>>> next_pow(1)
2
>>> next_pow(2)
4
>>> next_pow(3)
4
>>> next_pow(4)
8
>>> next_pow(123)
128
>>> next_pow(222)
256
>>>
```

Comment: Talking about assembly in a Python answer adds no value since Python uses byte code...

Answer (score 0):

Forget this! It uses loop !

```
     unsigned int nextPowerOf2 ( unsigned int u)
     {
         unsigned int v = 0x80000000; // supposed 32-bit unsigned int

         if (u < v) {
            while (v > u) v = v >> 1;
         }
         return (v << 1);  // return 0 if number is too big
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int nextHighestPower(int number){
    if((number & number-1)==0){
        return number;
    }
    else{
        int count=0;
        while(number!=0){
            number=number>>1;
            count++;
        }
        return 1<<count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
#define nextPowerOf2(x, n) (x + (n-1)) & ~(n-1)
```

or even

```
#define nextPowerOf2(x, n)  x + (x & (n-1))
```

Comment: This rounds up to the next *multiple* of some fixed power of two, `n`.  Or it's trying to; the second one is wrong, adding the low bits to themselves not necessarily clearing them.   The first one is right, e.g. rounding to a multiple of 16 by doing `(x+15) & -16`.   Anyway, this seems to be answering a different question.