# Efficient least significant set bit of "biginteger" class

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm writing a boardgame engine and I wrote a *10x10* bitboard class. The class holds an array of two *uint64's* and implements various bit operations. An important operation I didn't implement yet is `lsb()`. I know that I can do `lsb()` on the first integer and if it's *0* do it on the second. However, checking if it's *0* seems redundant. What would be the most efficient way to implement `lsb()`?

EDIT:
My current code is:

```
char s = lsb64(b_[0]);
if (s == 0 && b_[1] != 0) {
    s = lsb64(b_[1]) + 64;
}
return s;
```

lsb64() here returns 1 + the index of the bit

Are there performance improvements I could make? Note the if condition will almost always be false.

Comment: Show what you have done (or would try) and explain why you are not satisfied with it.

Comment: Assuming the first value is the least significant, you'd need to do some kind of test on it, surely?

Comment: @NeilKirk Yeah, I'm just not sure if testing if the first number is equal to 0 is the best way.

Comment: @jxh So the obvious approach to me is to use one of the various methods to do lsb() on the first integer, then check if the number was 0 to decide if you need to do lsb() on the second number.

Comment: As it is, you have not illustrated any effort on your part why you feel your hypothetical implementation is not acceptable.

Comment: @jxh Are you saying it is acceptable? I just don't understand cpu instructions well enough to know if that would be the best approach.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking and you haven't exhibited anything to critique. The least significant bit of any multi-precision integer is given by (`lsb & 1)` where `lsb` is the least significant byte: there is no reason to test more than one value. Do you mean 'lowest *set* bit'? which is a completely different thing?

Comment: @EJP Yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect most inputs to have the bit set in the lower 64 bits, you will have to profile the execution. The following avoids two `lsb64` calls.

```
return b_[0] ? lsb64(b_[0]) : (b_[1] ? 64 + lsb64(b_[1]) : 0);
```

Possible solutions to `lsb64` can be found in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3465098/315052).

Comment: Thanks. Actually, by far most inputs will have a bit set in the lower integer. Does that mean the upper solution will be faster?

Comment: Why do you check for x = 0 after looking for the lsb in x?

Comment: @NeilKirk Apparently there's a builtin function in gcc, __builtin_ffs,  which returns one plus the lsb index and 0 if it's 0.