# Find the most significant bit or log base 2 (floor) of a positive integer via straight line bit manipulation in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

This is what I need to do:

```
int lg(int v)
{
    int r = 0;
    while (v >>= 1) // unroll for more speed...
    {
        r++;
    }
}
```

I found the above solution at: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog

This works, butI need to do it without loops, control structures, or constants bigger than 0xFF (255), which has proven to be very hard for me to find.  I've been trying to figure something out using conditionals in the form

```
( x ? y : z ) = (((~(!!x) + 1)) & y) | ((~(~(!!x) + 1)) & z)
```

but I can't get it to work.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've vaguely recalling a way to find the least significant bit, but not the most significant.  But if you have to use conditionals you're probably not doing it right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compute fast log base 2 ceiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272424/compute-fast-log-base-2-ceiling)

Comment: Isn't the operator `? :` a control structure?

Comment: The second solution in your link already does what you're looking for (except it uses `0xFFFF` as a constant, but that's very easy to get rid of).

Comment: @us2012 That would work if it didn't employ the > statements.  Those are forbidden along with function calls of any kind.  I put the right hand side of the ? : expression since using it directly is not allowed either.  This is homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any control structure, not even the `?:` operator, you can simulate your own algo

```
int r = 0;

x >>= 1;
r += (x != 0);
x >>= 1;
r += (x != 0);
...
```

provided that, in C,

- *x* is assumed to be positive (otherwise having `int x=-1;` for instance  `x >>= 1` *n times* is always `!= 0`
- a condition like `x != 0` returns 0 (*false*) or 1 (*true)

Comment: != is not allowed, but I got around it by using the substitution I wrote above for x ? 1 : 0 , so I have r += (((~(!!x) + 1)) & 1) | ((~(~(!!x) + 1)) & 0) .  Your answer did the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a homework. Well, if you can't use control structures, a good alternative is to precalculate what you can: divide and conquer. Solve for a smaller part (one byte, one nibble, your choice), and apply to the parts of your integer.