# Check the Number of Powers of 2

Tags: algorithm, math, bit

I have a number X  , I want to check the number of powers of 2 it have ?
For Ex

```
N=7  ans is 2 , 2*2
N=20 ans is 4, 2*2*2*2
```

Similar I want to check the `next power of 2`

```
For Ex:
N=14 Ans=16
```

Is there any Bit Hack for this without using `for` loops ?
Like we are having a one line solution to check if it's a power of 2 `X&(X-1)==0`,similarly like that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Comment: @AlexeyGuseynov i guess number of set bit does not give me the correct answer

Comment: Like this `10000000001` setbit is 2 only

Comment: You mean "I need to compute the base 2 log", do you?

Comment: So basically the first quetsion is about getting the int part of the log base 2 of N. The second question already have tons of duplicates here http://stackoverflow.com/q/466204/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/671815/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3272424/995714

Answer (score 2):

GCC has a built-in instruction called [`__builtin_clz()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) that returns the number of leading zeros in an integer. So for example, assuming a 32-bit `int`, the expression `p = 32 - __builtin_clz(n)` will tell you how many bits are needed to store the integer `n`, and `1 << p` will give you the next highest power of 2 (provided `p`<32, of course).

There are also equivalent functions that work with `long` and `long long` integers.

Alternatively, `math.h` defines a function called `frexp()` that returns the base-2 exponent of a double-precision number. This is likely to be less efficient because your integer will have to be converted to a double-precision value before it is passed to this function.

Answer (score 0):

A number is power of two if it has only single '1' in its binary value. For example, 2 = 00000010, 4 = 00000100, 8 = 00001000 and so on. So you can check it using counting the no. of 1's in its bit value. If count is 1 then the number is power of 2 and vice versa.

You can take help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815165/how-to-implement-bitcount-using-only-bitwise-operators) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1) to avoid for loops for counting set bits.

If count is not 1 (means that Value is not power of 2) then take position of its first set bit from MSB and the next power of 2 value to this number is the value having only set bit at position + 1. For example, number 3 = 00000011. Its first set bit from MSB is 2nd bit. Therefore the next power of 2 number is a value having only set bit at 3rd position. i.e. 00000100 = 4.