# How to obtain the next Power Of Two of a given number?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bit twiddling: find next power of two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322510/bit-twiddling-find-next-power-of-two)

How to obtain the next Power Of Two of a given number?

For example, i receive the number 138, the next POT number is 256.

i receive the number 112, the next POT is 128.

I need to do an algorithm that calculates that

Thanks

Comment: This is homework, isn't it? You must tag homework as such.

Comment: Why is 256 instead of 128 the next POT for 112?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A really clever programmer would look at the `java.lang.Integer.highestOneBit(int)` method, and consider the left-shift operator (`<<`).

Comment: +1; didn't know that method existed!

Comment: A concrete formula is missing. Assuming the next power of two of 128 is 128, then what about `Math.max(1, Integer.highestOneBit(i - 1) << 1)`?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very simple algorithm (since this is homework, you'll have to code it up yourself):

1. Start with `1` as the first candidate power of two.
2. Keep shifting the candidate number by one bit to the left until it's greater than, or equal to, the target number.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the input is a positive integer, one unconventional solution would be to look at the bit pattern of the number. Find the first '1' from the left, then think about the value of the bit to the left of that.

Comment: can you explain me how to do it please?