# Find the smallest regular number that is not less than N

Tags: algorithm, math, prime-factoring, hamming-numbers, smooth-numbers

> [Regular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number) are numbers that evenly divide powers of 60. As an example, 60<sup>2</sup> = 3600 = 48 × 75, so both 48 and 75 are divisors of a power of 60. Thus, they are also regular numbers.

This is an extension of [rounding up to the next power of two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322510/bit-twiddling-find-next-power-of-two).

I have an integer value *N* which may contain large prime factors and I want to round it up to a number composed of only small prime factors (2, 3 and 5)

Examples:

- `f(18) == 18 == 21 * 32`
- `f(19) == 20 == 22 * 51`
- `f(257) == 270 == 21 * 33 * 51`

What would be an efficient way to find the *smallest* number satisfying this requirement?

The values involved may be large, so I would like to avoid enumerating all regular numbers starting from 1 or maintaining an array of all possible values.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the citations in the "Algorithms" section of [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number#Algorithms) you linked, or the related article on [smooth numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number)?

Comment: @Jordan yes, I am familiar with the lazy functional technique for generating all regular numbers (which could be used as a brute-force solution for my problem.)  I also read the part about estimating the number of smooth numbers in a range.  Do you think this might be useful here?  If so feel free to put it in an answer!

Comment: Also known as "Hamming numbers" "ugly numbers" and "5-smooth numbers".  Useful for choose sizes of data to do FFTs on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, hopefully third time's a charm here.  A recursive, branching algorithm for an initial input of p, where N is the number being 'built' within each thread. NB 3a-c here are launched as separate threads or otherwise done (quasi-)asynchronously.

1. Calculate the next-largest power of 2 after p, call this R.  N = p.
2. Is N > R? Quit this thread.  Is p composed of only small prime factors? You're done.  Otherwise, go to step 3.
3. After any of 3a-c, go to step 4.

   a) Round p up to the nearest multiple of 2.  This number can be expressed as m * 2.
   b) Round p up to the nearest multiple of 3.  This number can be expressed as m * 3.
   c) Round p up to the nearest multiple of 5.  This number can be expressed as m * 5.
4. Go to step 2, with p = m.

I've omitted the bookkeeping to do regarding keeping track of N but that's fairly straightforward I take it.

Edit: Forgot 6, thanks ypercube.

Edit 2: Had this up to 30, (5, 6, 10, 15, 30) realized that was unnecessary, took that out.

Edit 3: (The last one I promise!) Added the power-of-30 check, which helps prevent this algorithm from eating up all your RAM.

Edit 4: Changed power-of-30 to power-of-2, per finnw's observation.

Comment: In step 1, can you not use the next largest power of 2 instead of 30?

Comment: @finnw Yes, you're right.  Breaking my promise and editing accordingly.

Comment: Have you implemented this?  I have tried to follow how this algorithm will proceed when N=1025; The best solution is 1080 but I don't think it will find it.

Comment: @finnw Admittedly not, but for your example the you'd get the following sequence: 1025 -> 1026 = 2 x 513 -> 514 = 2 x 257 -> 258 = 2 x 129 -> 129 = 3 x 43 -> 45 = 3 x 15 -> 15 = 3 x 5.  Then N at this point = 2 x 2 x 2 x 3 x 3 x 3 x 5 = 1080.  Key is that in some cases 'rounding up' is vacuous, if the factor is already present.  Now there will be *many* paths generated and what your example makes me realize is that the first path to finish might not always have the smallest N.  So I think you have to wait until *all* threads terminate, sort, and take the lowest.

Comment: @finnw But the next power of 2 = 1089, so I don't think this would lead to a combinatorial disaster.

Comment: @finnw Correction, you don't need to save them all and sort, you just keep a record of the current lowest N and update when a better one comes along.

Comment: Ok, I assumed it would start with 1025 -> 25 × 41, which is valid but leads to a worse solution.

Comment: These edit notes are confusing, presumably because the things mentioned no longer exist? Why not just leave them in the edit history?  That's what it's for.

Comment: This answer works only if one starts with "p = 1" (with some validity checks for input integers less than one) which isn't specified in the text, and is inefficient as compared to later answers by WillNess and @endolith, which only loop by two of the three variables, as the third one is implied by the other two.

Answer (score 7):

One can produce arbitrarily thin a [slice of the Hamming sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10160054/849891) around the n-th member in time `~ n^(2/3)` by direct enumeration of triples `(i,j,k)` such that `N = 2^i * 3^j * 5^k`.

The algorithm works from `log2(N) = i+j*log2(3)+k*log2(5)`; enumerates all possible `k`s and for each, all possible `j`s, finds the top `i` and thus the triple `(k,j,i)` and keeps it in a "band" if inside the given "width" below the given high logarithmic top value (when `width` < 1 there can be at most one such `i`) then sorts them by their logarithms.

[WP says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number#Number_theory) that `n ~ (log N)^3`, i.e. run time `~ (log N)^2`.  Here we don't care for the exact position of the found triple in the sequence, so all the count calculations from [the original code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers#Direct_calculation_through_triples_enumeration) can be thrown away:

```hs
slice hi w = sortBy (compare `on` fst) b where       -- hi>log2(N) is a top value
  lb5=logBase 2 5 ; lb3=logBase 2 3                  -- w<1 (NB!) is log2(width)
  b  = concat                                        -- the slice
      [ [ (r,(i,j,k)) | frac < w ]                   -- store it, if inside width
        | k <- [ 0 .. floor ( hi   /lb5) ],  let p = fromIntegral k*lb5,
          j <- [ 0 .. floor ((hi-p)/lb3) ],  let q = fromIntegral j*lb3 + p,
          let (i,frac)=properFraction(hi-q) ;    r = hi - frac ]   -- r = i + q
                    -- properFraction 12.7 == (12, 0.7)

-- update: in pseudocode:
def slice(hi, w):
    lb5, lb3 = logBase(2, 5), logBase(2, 3)  -- logs base 2 of 5 and 3
    for k from 0 step 1 to floor(hi/lb5) inclusive:
        p = k*lb5
        for j from 0 step 1 to floor((hi-p)/lb3) inclusive:
           q = j*lb3 + p
           i = floor(hi-q)
           frac = hi-q-i                     -- frac < 1 , always
           r = hi - frac                     -- r == i + q
           if frac < w:
              place (r,(i,j,k)) into the output array
   sort the output array's entries by their "r" component
        in ascending order, and return thus sorted array
```

Having enumerated the triples in the slice, it is a simple matter of sorting and searching, taking practically `O(1)` time (for *arbitrarily thin* a slice) to find the first triple above `N`. Well, actually, for constant width (logarithmic), the amount of numbers in the slice (members of the "upper crust" in the `(i,j,k)`-space below the `log(N)` plane) is again `m ~ n^2/3 ~ (log N)^2` and sorting takes `m log m` time (so that searching, even linear, takes `~ m` run time then). But the width can be made smaller for bigger `N`s, following some empirical observations; and constant factors for the enumeration of triples are much higher than for the subsequent sorting anyway.

Even with constant width (logarthmic) it runs very fast, calculating the 1,000,000-th value in the Hamming sequence [instantly](http://ideone.com/q3fma) and [the billionth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37833043/849891) in 0.05s.

The original idea of "top band of triples" is due to Louis Klauder, as cited in [my post on a DDJ blogs discussion](http://drdobbs.com/blogs/architecture-and-design/228700538) back in 2008.

*update:* as noted by [GordonBGood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549617/gordonbgood) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242733/find-the-smallest-regular-number-that-is-not-less-than-n/12041774#comment65615881_12041774), there's no need for the whole band but rather just about one or two values above and below the target. The algorithm is easily amended to that effect. The input should also be tested for being a Hamming number itself *before* proceeding with the algorithm, to avoid round-off issues with double precision. There are no round-off issues comparing the logarithms of the Hamming numbers known in advance to be different (though [going up to a trillionth entry](http://ideone.com/q3fma) in the sequence uses about 14 significant digits in logarithm values, leaving only 1-2 digits to spare, so the situation may in fact be turning iffy there; but for 1-billionth we only need 11 significant digits).

*update2:* turns out the Double precision for logarithms limits this to numbers below about 20,000 to 40,000 decimal digits (i.e. 10 trillionth to 100 trillionth Hamming number). If there's a real need for this for such big numbers, the algorithm can be switched back to working with the Integer values themselves instead of their logarithms, which will be slower.

Comment: I wish I understood Haskell.  :/  This looks superficially like the best answer.

Comment: @endolith this here is very basic stuff. `f x y` is a function application, `f(x,y)`. the list comprehension `[x | p x]` is a list containing one `x` if `p(x)` is true; empty otherwise. list comprehension `[x | k <- [0..10], j<- [k..10], let x=k+j*42]` pulls each `k` from a range from 0 to 10, and for each k it pulls each `j` from a range from `k` to 10 (as if there were two nested loops there). `properFraction` is a built-in, for e.g. 3.14 it returns a pair `(3,0.14)`. `fst(a,b) == a` is another built-in. `concat` concatenates lists in a given list, to form one list: `[[1],[],[3]] --> [1,3]`.

Comment: @endolith lastly, `fromIntegral i*x` is `fromIntegral(i) * x` is just `i*x`, where `i` is a value of some integer-like type, and `x` some floating type. `fromIntegral` is like a type cast; we aren't allowed to multiply an int and a double directly, in Haskell. so the algo goes from `log2(N) = i+j*log2(3)+k*log2(5)`; enumerates all possible `k`s and for each, all possible `j`s, finds the top `i` and thus the triple `(k,j,i)` and keeps it if inside the given "width" below the given `high` logarithmic top value (when `width < 1` there can be only one such `i`) then sorts them by their logvals.

Comment: Does this produce the right output for n=11?  I tried to do it on ideone and it outputs (0,1,1), which I think means 3*5=15, but the next regular number is 12 which would be (2,1,0) = 2^2*3.  Also it's supposed to be the next regular number >= to n, but this seems to calculate the next regular number > n?

Comment: @endolith running that ideone entry with 11 as its input produces the 11-th number in the Hamming sequence, 1-based. Running it with a character 'a' as input produces first 20 elements in the sequence: [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,16,18,20,24,25,27,30,32,36]. As you can see, the 11-th number there is 15.

Comment: What isn't specified here is that we don't need to save a band at all as we can just check for the each <= the input.  Also unspecified is the problem of using the log representation as to precision: with round-off errors: if the input value is already a regular number, the log approximation comparison may find the the approximate log is either slightly too high or slightly too low than the log approximation of the input answer.  To solve this, one needs to keep a couple of values above and a couple below the input value, then as a final step scan for the real number minimum <= the input.

Comment: @GordonBGood precision is good enough for comparing the logarithms of pretty large (how large? interesting question) Hamming numbers *known* to be different, so, just need to pre-test the input for being a Hamming number already. Then you're of course correct, keeping a couple of values above the target logarithm and one below is enough, and after the band enumeration, perform a couple of bigint comparisons.

Comment: @GordonBGood 1T-th number calculation seems to be using 13 significant digits in Double logvals.

Comment: @GordonBGood correction: [14 significant digits](http://ideone.com/q3fma) (see the new output at the page's bottom).

Comment: @WillNess, as noted, my calculations indicate that the requirement for more digits grows very slowly with range, and that there is likely enough precision so we will run out of time before we run out of room.  I think that most will find it adequate if we can "HammingRound" for input numbers of a million digits in a reasonable time.  I now think we should calculate lower and upper bounds based on the error precision to guarantee that there is at least one value less than or equal to and greater than the input, then go back to putting these in a sorted band before final qualification.

Comment: I also think that "just need to pre-test the input for being a Hamming number already" isn't a good idea as that requires a lot of bigint ops:  repeatedly dividing by 5 and 3 until the remainder is not zero and then making sure that the final remainder is a power of two.  Since we already will produce a band of values spanning the number, the final check will find if the input number is one of them with just a few bigint comparisons.

Comment: @GordonBGood BigFloat was a wrong turn. it is x1000 slower than Double. Instead, I've added the check for `isBandTrulySorted = let a=map (trival.snd) s in and $ zipWith (>) a (tail a)` which calculates actual Integer values from all the *triples* in the sorted band, and compares them to check whether the band was indeed sorted. 100T was still sorted (3.3 minutes) but 1000 trillion was *not* (15.2 minutes run time on my box).

Comment: I need to sleep on these sorts of problems before coming up with an answer.  I think we are ok if we extend the precision from using the 52-bit positive mantisa of double to using a pseudo decimal Word64 logrep with the pseudo decimal shifted in 'x' binary places leaving '64-x' binary places for the whole part.  It may be slightly faster on 64-bit code too as using integer rather than FP operations, although slower on 32-bit code for the 64-bit ops.  Then a 24-bit whole part and a 40-bit frac should do the job.  I'll produce some code in a day or two, but taking some personal time.

Comment: @GordonBGood or just switch back to Integer values themselves from their logarithms, so sort won't be a problem and the slowdown hopefully won't be severe. Then the only remaining problem is the enumeration, which will have to be tweaked somehow as well. And *here*, as you've pointed out, the sort isn't needed at all so actually implementing your suggestion will help. But whether there is *any* need *at all* for this, with the numbers bigger than about 20,000 decimal digits, is quite another question entirely. :)

Comment: Your isSorted check is actually quite good as a band will likely/almost certainly contain some values with low j/k and some with high.  Using that showed that only 40 binary decimal digits of precision was not adequate, so the logrep needs to be larger than 64 bits for extended ranges.  There is likely some benefit to using log multi-precision Integer's instead of Integers directly due to the greatly reduced log range but my testing shows that it is still 20X slower.  You are probably right that we should just limit this to output values of 50,000 digits or so., especially for this question.

Comment: WillNess, Please have a look at my answer which includes both Python and Haskell codes.  These codes don't use hardly any memory or Integer calculations at all, and you will see the completion of my idea to minimize the compare band to only a few values above the target.  I had implemented your sorted "error band" solution, and then picked the match to the criteria of the minimum >= the target by binary search in order to minimize the number of values compared, but with the success of this extremely narrow band idea, there doesn't seem to be any point.

Comment: @GordonBGood interesting, thanks; when I get a chance. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution in Python, based on [Will Ness answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12041774/125507) but taking some shortcuts and using pure integer math to avoid running into log space numerical accuracy errors:

```py
import math

def next_regular(target):
    """
    Find the next regular number greater than or equal to target.
    """
    # Check if it's already a power of 2 (or a non-integer)
    try:
        if not (target & (target-1)):
            return target
    except TypeError:
        # Convert floats/decimals for further processing
        target = int(math.ceil(target))

    if target <= 6:
        return target

    match = float('inf') # Anything found will be smaller
    p5 = 1
    while p5 < target:
        p35 = p5
        while p35 < target:
            # Ceiling integer division, avoiding conversion to float
            # (quotient = ceil(target / p35))
            # From https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511341/125507
            quotient = -(-target // p35)

            # Quickly find next power of 2 >= quotient
            # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19164783/125507
            try:
                p2 = 2**((quotient - 1).bit_length())
            except AttributeError:
                # Fallback for Python <2.7
                p2 = 2**(len(bin(quotient - 1)) - 2)

            N = p2 * p35
            if N == target:
                return N
            elif N < match:
                match = N
            p35 *= 3
            if p35 == target:
                return p35
        if p35 < match:
            match = p35
        p5 *= 5
        if p5 == target:
            return p5
    if p5 < match:
        match = p5
    return match
```

In English: iterate through every combination of 5s and 3s, quickly finding the next power of 2 >= target for each pair and keeping the smallest result.  (It's a waste of time to iterate through every possible multiple of 2 if only one of them can be correct).  It also returns early if it ever finds that the target is already a regular number, though this is not strictly necessary.

I've tested it pretty thoroughly, testing every integer from 0 to 51200000 and comparing to the list on OEIS http://oeis.org/A051037, as well as many large numbers that are ±1 from regular numbers, etc. It's [now available in SciPy as `fftpack.helper.next_fast_len`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len.html), to find optimal sizes for FFTs ([source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/fftpack/helper.py#L54-L154)).

I'm not sure if the log method is faster because I couldn't get it to work reliably enough to test it.  I think it has a similar number of operations, though?  I'm not sure, but this is reasonably fast.  Takes <3 seconds (or 0.7 second with gmpy) to calculate that 2<sup>142</sup> × 3<sup>80</sup> × 5<sup>444</sup> is the next regular number above 2<sup>2</sup> × 3<sup>454</sup> × 5<sup>249</sup>+1 (the 100,000,000th regular number, which has 392 digits)

Comment: You are right that the log method takes about the same number of operations, just much faster as it doesn't have to deal with multi-precision math.  The problem with getting it to work is that these are approximations, and especially if the input value is already a regular number, the determined log for it as compared to the generated regular number log may not quite match due to round-off errors.  The solution is to add a bit of logic to keep a couple of values just <= and a couple just > for the log comparison, then as a final step convert these to bigint and find min >= the input value.

Comment: @GordonBGood That sounds like a good idea.  Want to post an answer? :)

Comment: the precision is usually enough to compare [quite large Hamming numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824301/1-billionth-ugly-or-hamming-number/37833043#37833043) that are *known* to be different. Here, just pre-test the input whether it's already a regular number or not.

Comment: Working on an answer; need to estimate the difference in precision between an approximate log determined directly and one calculated through the regular number loops.  @WillNess, yes, the precision is adequate to compare very large Hamming numbers (10 million digits or so) as those become very sparse with range, but this needs to be compared to the approximate log of the input value determined by other means (for the input number), which doesn't have the same error terms.

Comment: @GordonBGood have you missed my other recent comment? at 1T-th (~8500 digits), there's only room for 2-3 significant digits left in the logarithm values (w/ Doubles, of course; can always switch to ratios but that'll be slower). we're talking about comparing logvals, yes? there's no opportunity for error to accumulate in the loops, as the values are not accumulated with (+), but re-calculated with (*). for 1T-th, max logval is 28052.292341476037, and min distance between logvals in the band is 2.9831426218152046e-9. So, even worse, about 1 spare digit left.

Comment: @WillNess, My thinking was based on 53 bit precision with one bit sign for double.  If the lb3 and lb5 log2 values are good for every bit, the '2' log is exact, and the logrep is a sum of the log2 3 multiple and the log2 5 multiple (with less multiples for a given range for the large ones), then there would be about 26 bits accuracy for a log2 value of about 64 million or about 20 million decimal digits although that's slow.  I think that for very large ranges, the required extra digits grow very slowly, so double may be adequate.

Comment: @WillNess,   For the original algorithm, the error needs to be low enough so that the absolute error in max j * lb3 and max k * lb5 never exceeds 1 (the difference between successive powers of 2 in log2 values) or each others errors for lesser values of j and k for the relative comparisons to be accurate.  Using Windows calculator, the lb3 and lb5 values seem to be good enough so we don't have to worry until about 2^10^15 or so or billions of digits and we would never even want to calculate more than a few million in a few days anyway ;)  I think it is adequate.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use `float('inf')`? Isn't there a power of two between `target` and `2 * target`?

Comment: @DrorSpeiser Is it hurting anything to use infinity?  It will find the next power of two inside the loop

Comment: @endolith: nah, of course it's fine. Everything else is done in integers, that's all :)

Comment: @endolith, please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53427132/549617) which carries this work forward and is faster due to using logarithms for mostly eliminate the bigint operations.

Answer (score 3):

You want to find the smallest number `m` that is `m >= N` and `m = 2^i * 3^j * 5^k` where all `i,j,k >= 0`.

Taking logarithms the equations can be rewritten as:

```
 log m >= log N
 log m = i*log2 + j*log3 + k*log5
```

You can calculate `log2`, `log3`, `log5` and `logN` to (enough high, depending on the size of `N`) accuracy. Then this problem looks like a [Integer Linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_linear_programming#Integer_unknowns) problem and you could try to solve it using one of the known algorithms for this NP-hard problem.

Comment: The transformated problem is (in general) NP-hard. This particular instance of the general Integer Programming problem may have nicer solutions. Or the original (non-tranformated) number theory problem may have nicer algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED/CORRECTED:**  Corrected the codes to pass the [scipy tests](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/fftpack/tests/test_helper.py#L64):

Here's an answer based on [endolith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649737/549617), but almost eliminating long multi-precision integer calculations by using float64 logarithm representations to do a base comparison to find triple values that pass the criteria, only resorting to full precision comparisons when there is a chance that the logarithm value may not be accurate enough, which only occurs when the target is very close to either the previous or the next regular number:

```
import math

def next_regulary(target):
    """
    Find the next regular number greater than or equal to target.
    """
    if target < 2: return ( 0, 0, 0 )
    log2hi = 0
    mant = 0
    # Check if it's already a power of 2 (or a non-integer)
    try:
        mant = target & (target - 1)
        target = int(target) # take care of case where not int/float/decimal
    except TypeError:
        # Convert floats/decimals for further processing
        target = int(math.ceil(target))
        mant = target & (target - 1)

    # Quickly find next power of 2 >= target
    # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19164783/125507
    try:
        log2hi = target.bit_length()
    except AttributeError:
        # Fallback for Python <2.7
        log2hi = len(bin(target)) - 2

    # exit if this is a power of two already...
    if not mant: return ( log2hi - 1, 0, 0 )

    # take care of trivial cases...
    if target < 9:
        if target < 4: return ( 0, 1, 0 )
        elif target < 6: return ( 0, 0, 1 )
        elif target < 7: return ( 1, 1, 0 )
        else: return ( 3, 0, 0 )

    # find log of target, which may exceed the float64 limit...
    if log2hi < 53: mant = target << (53 - log2hi)
    else: mant = target >> (log2hi - 53)
    log2target = log2hi + math.log2(float(mant) / (1 << 53))

    # log2 constants
    log2of2 = 1.0; log2of3 = math.log2(3); log2of5 = math.log2(5)

    # calculate range of log2 values close to target;
    # desired number has a logarithm of log2target <= x <= top...
    fctr = 6 * log2of3 * log2of5
    top = (log2target**3 + 2 * fctr)**(1/3) # for up to 2 numbers higher
    btm = 2 * log2target - top # or up to 2 numbers lower

    match = log2hi # Anything found will be smaller
    result = ( log2hi, 0, 0 ) # placeholder for eventual matches
    count = 0 # only used for debugging counting band
    fives = 0; fiveslmt = int(math.ceil(top / log2of5))
    while fives < fiveslmt:
        log2p = top - fives * log2of5
        threes = 0; threeslmt = int(math.ceil(log2p / log2of3))
        while threes < threeslmt:
            log2q = log2p - threes * log2of3
            twos = int(math.floor(log2q)); log2this = top - log2q + twos

            if log2this >= btm: count += 1 # only used for counting band
            if log2this >= btm and log2this < match:
                # logarithm precision may not be enough to differential between
                # the next lower regular number and the target, so do
                # a full resolution comparison to eliminate this case...
                if (2**twos * 3**threes * 5**fives) >= target:
                    match = log2this; result = ( twos, threes, fives )
            threes += 1
        fives += 1

    return result

print(next_regular(2**2 * 3**454 * 5**249 + 1)) # prints (142, 80, 444)
```

Since most long multi-precision calculations have been eliminated, gmpy isn't needed, and on IDEOne the above code takes 0.11 seconds instead of 0.48 seconds for endolith's solution to find the next regular number greater than the 100 millionth one as shown; it takes 0.49 seconds instead of 5.48 seconds to find the next regular number past the billionth (next one is `(761,572,489)` past `(1334,335,404) + 1`), and the difference will get even larger as the range goes up as the multi-precision calculations get increasingly longer for the endolith version compared to almost none here.  Thus, this version could calculate the next regular number from the trillionth in the sequence in about 50 seconds on IDEOne, where it would likely take over an hour with the endolith version.

The English description of the algorithm is almost the same as for the endolith version, differing as follows:
  1) calculates the float log estimation of the argument target value (we can't use the built-in `log` function directly as the range may be much too large for representation as a 64-bit float),
  2) compares the log representation values in determining qualifying values inside an estimated range above and below the target value of only about two or three numbers (depending on round-off),
  3) compare multi-precision values only if within the above defined narrow band,
  4) outputs the triple indices rather than the full long multi-precision integer (would be about 840 decimal digits for the one past the billionth, ten times that for the trillionth), which can then easily be converted to the long multi-precision value if required.

This algorithm uses almost no memory other than for the potentially very large multi-precision integer target value, the intermediate evaluation comparison values of about the same size, and the output expansion of the triples if required.  This algorithm is an improvement over the endolith version in that it successfully uses the logarithm values for most comparisons in spite of their lack of precision, and that it narrows the band of compared numbers to just a few.

This algorithm will work for argument ranges somewhat above ten trillion (a few minute's calculation time at IDEOne rates) when it will no longer be correct due to lack of precision in the log representation values as per @WillNess's discussion; in order to fix this, we can change the log representation to a "roll-your-own" logarithm representation consisting of a fixed-length integer (124 bits for about double the exponent range, good for targets of over a hundred thousand digits if one is willing to wait); this will be a little slower due to the smallish multi-precision integer operations being slower than float64 operations, but not that much slower since the size is limited (maybe a factor of three or so slower).

Now none of these Python implementations (without using C or Cython or PyPy or something) are particularly fast, as they are about a hundred times slower than as implemented in a compiled language.  For reference sake, here is a Haskell version:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O3 #-}

import Data.Word
import Data.Bits

nextRegular :: Integer -> ( Word32, Word32, Word32 )
nextRegular target
  | target < 2                   = ( 0, 0, 0 )
  | target .&. (target - 1) == 0 = ( fromIntegral lg2hi - 1, 0, 0 )
  | target < 9                   = case target of
                                     3 -> ( 0, 1, 0 )
                                     5 -> ( 0, 0, 1 )
                                     6 -> ( 1, 1, 0 )
                                     _ -> ( 3, 0, 0 )
  | otherwise                    = match
 where
  lg3 = logBase 2 3 :: Double; lg5 = logBase 2 5 :: Double
  lg2hi = let cntplcs v cnt =
                let nv = v `shiftR` 31 in
                if nv <= 0 then
                  let cntbts x c =
                        if x <= 0 then c else
                        case c + 1 of
                          nc -> nc `seq` cntbts (x `shiftR` 1) nc in
                  cntbts (fromIntegral v :: Word32) cnt
                else case cnt + 31 of ncnt -> ncnt `seq` cntplcs nv ncnt
          in cntplcs target 0
  lg2tgt = let mant = if lg2hi <= 53 then target `shiftL` (53 - lg2hi)
                      else target `shiftR` (lg2hi - 53)
           in fromIntegral lg2hi +
                logBase 2 (fromIntegral mant / 2^53 :: Double)
  lg2top = (lg2tgt^3 + 2 * 6 * lg3 * lg5)**(1/3) -- for 2 numbers or so higher
  lg2btm = 2* lg2tgt - lg2top -- or two numbers or so lower
  match =
    let klmt = floor (lg2top / lg5)
        loopk k mtchlgk mtchtplk =
          if k > klmt then mtchtplk else
          let p = lg2top - fromIntegral k * lg5
              jlmt = fromIntegral $ floor (p / lg3)
              loopj j mtchlgj mtchtplj =
                if j > jlmt then loopk (k + 1) mtchlgj mtchtplj else
                let q = p - fromIntegral j * lg3
                    ( i, frac ) = properFraction q; r = lg2top - frac
                    ( nmtchlg, nmtchtpl ) =
                      if r < lg2btm || r >= mtchlgj then
                        ( mtchlgj, mtchtplj ) else
                      if 2^i * 3^j * 5^k >= target then
                        ( r, ( i, j, k ) ) else ( mtchlgj, mtchtplj )
                in nmtchlg `seq` nmtchtpl `seq` loopj (j + 1) nmtchlg nmtchtpl
          in loopj 0 mtchlgk mtchtplk
    in loopk 0 (fromIntegral lg2hi) ( fromIntegral lg2hi, 0, 0 )


trival :: ( Word32, Word32, Word32 ) -> Integer
trival (i,j,k) = 2^i * 3^j * 5^k

main = putStrLn $ show $ nextRegular $ (trival (1334,335,404)) + 1 -- (1126,16930,40)
```

This code calculates the next regular number following the billionth in too small a time to be measured and following the trillionth in 0.69 seconds on IDEOne (and potentially could run even faster except that IDEOne doesn't support LLVM).  Even Julia will run at something like this Haskell speed after the "warm-up" for JIT compilation.

**EDIT_ADD:**  The Julia code is as per the following:

```
function nextregular(target :: BigInt) :: Tuple{ UInt32, UInt32, UInt32 }
    # trivial case of first value or anything less...
    target < 2 && return ( 0, 0, 0 )

    # Check if it's already a power of 2 (or a non-integer)
    mant = target & (target - 1)

    # Quickly find next power of 2 >= target
    log2hi :: UInt32 = 0
    test = target
    while true
        next = test & 0x7FFFFFFF
        test >>>= 31; log2hi += 31
        test <= 0 && (log2hi -= leading_zeros(UInt32(next)) - 1; break)
    end

    # exit if this is a power of two already...
    mant == 0 && return ( log2hi - 1, 0, 0 )

    # take care of trivial cases...
    if target < 9
        target < 4 && return ( 0, 1, 0 )
        target < 6 && return ( 0, 0, 1 )
        target < 7 && return ( 1, 1, 0 )
        return ( 3, 0, 0 )
    end

    # find log of target, which may exceed the Float64 limit...
    if log2hi < 53 mant = target << (53 - log2hi)
    else mant = target >>> (log2hi - 53) end
    log2target = log2hi + log(2, Float64(mant) / (1 << 53))

    # log2 constants
    log2of2 = 1.0; log2of3 = log(2, 3); log2of5 = log(2, 5)

    # calculate range of log2 values close to target;
    # desired number has a logarithm of log2target <= x <= top...
    fctr = 6 * log2of3 * log2of5
    top = (log2target^3 + 2 * fctr)^(1/3) # for 2 numbers or so higher
    btm = 2 * log2target - top # or 2 numbers or so lower

    # scan for values in the given narrow range that satisfy the criteria...
    match = log2hi # Anything found will be smaller
    result :: Tuple{UInt32,UInt32,UInt32} = ( log2hi, 0, 0 ) # placeholder for eventual matches
    fives :: UInt32 = 0; fiveslmt = UInt32(ceil(top / log2of5))
    while fives < fiveslmt
        log2p = top - fives * log2of5
        threes :: UInt32 = 0; threeslmt = UInt32(ceil(log2p / log2of3))
        while threes < threeslmt
            log2q = log2p - threes * log2of3
            twos = UInt32(floor(log2q)); log2this = top - log2q + twos

            if log2this >= btm && log2this < match
                # logarithm precision may not be enough to differential between
                # the next lower regular number and the target, so do
                # a full resolution comparison to eliminate this case...
                if (big(2)^twos * big(3)^threes * big(5)^fives) >= target
                    match = log2this; result = ( twos, threes, fives )
                end
            end
            threes += 1
        end
        fives += 1
    end
    result
end
```

Comment: Cool.  Did you run all the tests on it? https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/fftpack/tests/test_helper.py#L64  Is it faster for small numbers (~10000) or just for huge ones?

Comment: @endolith, it isn't faster (not much different) for small arguments, but increasingly faster for larger arguments.  Thank's for the link to the tests; I used them to find a couple of problems in the code, which have now been corrected.  The current corrected code passes all of the provided tests..

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility I just thought of:

If *N* is *X* bits long, then the smallest regular number *R* ≥ *N* will be in the range
`[2X-1, 2X]`

e.g. if *N* = 257 (binary `100000001`) then we know *R* is `1xxxxxxxx` unless *R* is exactly equal to the next power of 2 (512)

To generate all the regular numbers in this range, we can generate the odd regular numbers (i.e. multiples of powers of 3 and 5) first, then take each value and multiply by 2 (by bit-shifting) as many times as necessary to bring it into this range.

In Python:

```py
from itertools import ifilter, takewhile
from Queue import PriorityQueue

def nextPowerOf2(n):
    p = max(1, n)
    while p != (p & -p):
        p += p & -p
    return p

# Generate multiples of powers of 3, 5
def oddRegulars():
    q = PriorityQueue()
    q.put(1)
    prev = None
    while not q.empty():
        n = q.get()
        if n != prev:
            prev = n
            yield n
            if n % 3 == 0:
                q.put(n // 3 * 5)
            q.put(n * 3)

# Generate regular numbers with the same number of bits as n
def regularsCloseTo(n):
    p = nextPowerOf2(n)
    numBits = len(bin(n))
    for i in takewhile(lambda x: x <= p, oddRegulars()):
        yield i << max(0, numBits - len(bin(i)))

def nextRegular(n):
    bigEnough = ifilter(lambda x: x >= n, regularsCloseTo(n))
    return min(bigEnough)
```

Comment: hi, I've added a new answer here that shows how to directly enumerate (i,j,k) triples in the narrow vicinity of log(N), which is very fast.

Comment: actually, this is pretty close in its intention to what I posted, just differs in implementation. :)

Comment: This fails for nextRegular(7), nextRegular(31), nextRegular(61), etc. with `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence`

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a small c# program to solve this problem. It's not very optimised but it's a start.
This solution is pretty fast for numbers as big as 11 digits.

```cs
private long GetRegularNumber(long n)
{
    long result = n - 1;
    long quotient = result;

    while (quotient > 1)
    {
        result++;
        quotient = result;

        quotient = RemoveFactor(quotient, 2);
        quotient = RemoveFactor(quotient, 3);
        quotient = RemoveFactor(quotient, 5);
    }

    return result;
}

private static long RemoveFactor(long dividend, long divisor)
{
    long remainder = 0;
    long quotient = dividend;
    while (remainder == 0)
    {
        dividend = quotient;
        quotient = Math.DivRem(dividend, divisor, out remainder);
    }
    return dividend;
}
```

Comment: Is C# the right language for this?  Won't it be slower, particularly in iterations, than C or C++?

Comment: I'm pretty sure any programmer can rewrite this in c/c++ fairly easy. C# was the quickest way for me to test my idea.

Comment: `N_i ~ exp( i^(1/3) )` i.e. gaps between Hamming numbers grow exponentially. So your approach will experience a very pronounced slowdown as the numbers grow in magnitude, so it seems. 11 digits is not very big.

Answer (score -1):

You know what?  I'll put money on the proposition that actually, the 'dumb' algorithm is fastest.  This is based on the observation that the next regular number does not, in general, seem to be much larger than the given input.  So simply start counting up, and after each increment, refactor and see if you've found a regular number.  But create one processing thread for each available core you have, and for N cores have each thread examine every Nth number.  When each thread has found a number or crossed the power-of-2 threshold, compare the results (keep a running best number) and there you are.

Comment: Yes it would be interesting to benchmark it.  I expect you are right if we are talking about small numbers (< 10000 or so.)  But as the numbers get larger so do the distances between regular numbers.  An extreme example is 48000001 (the next regular number is 48600000, and it will take 2.8M divisions to find it.)

Comment: hi, I've added a new answer here that shows how to directly enumerate (i,j,k) triples in the narrow vicinity of log(N), which is very fast.

Comment: "This is based on the observation that the next regular number does not, in general, seem to be much larger than the given input." I don't think that's a good assumption.  They get farther and father apart as you go up.  The next regular number above 50000001 is 50331648, and that's only the 995th number. I suspect generating the list of regular numbers until you get one above your target is faster.

Comment: I tested an "iterate and factor" algorithm vs a "generate list until you go over" algorithm.  The factoring algorithm is faster for small numbers, but gets far slower for large numbers.  854296876 → 859963392 takes 26 ms vs 18 seconds with the factoring method.

Comment: in fact, the nth Hamming number's magnitude is M(n) ~ exp(n**(1/3)), so they grow exponentially more and more apart as n grows.

Comment: but their *logarithms* grow [ever so closer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60803224/hamming-numbers-and-double-precision/60805693#60805693).