# Ceil and floor equivalent in Python 3 without Math module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to ceil and floor 3/2 result (1.5) without using `import math`.

`math.floor(3/2)` => `3//2`
`math.ceil(3/2)` => ?

OK, here is the problem:
to sum all numbers
15 + 45 + 15 + 45 + 15 ...
with N items.

`sum = (n//2) * 5 + int(n/2) * 15`

Comment: wrong result for 4/2

Comment: Why not just use the `math` library?

Comment: for education purposes

Comment: Believe me, I tried. BTW I used PHP before, now I'm learning Python :)

Comment: Use the ceiling division operator, `--0--`!  This converts floor division to ceiling division.  For example, `--0-- 3//2` gives the ceiling of `3/2`.  Try it if you don't believe me!  (Okay, so you could spell it without the leading `--`, but it looks better with it.)

Comment: @Ffisegydd: There's at least one good reason to avoid the math library here, which is that by going via floating-point you can lose precision (and get the wrong answer as a result).

Comment: @zooks: More seriously, use the fact that `ceiling(x)` == `-floor(-x)` for any real number `x`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a ceiling equivalent of // operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822184/is-there-a-ceiling-equivalent-of-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
>>> 3/2
1.5
>>> 3//2 # floor
1
>>> -(-3//2) # ceil
2
```

Comment: funny that 
`>>>math.ceil(4.0000000000000001/2)` is
2, but
`>>>math.ceil(4.000000000000001/2)` is
3

Comment: But not surprising, when you consider that `4.0000000000000001 == 4.0` is `True` but `4.000000000000001 == 4.0` is False

Comment: based on two comments above, is it safe to say that those two methods are not reliable?

Comment: @farisfath25 No, the functions are not the issue.  It is always unsafe to rely on more bits of precision in a floating-point number than are guaranteed to be accurate.  At least one of those numbers cannot be represented perfectly in the floating-point system used by Python and/or the representation available on the particular processor it is running on.  If you need perfect precision, you must use an arbitrary-width representation.

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
def ceil(n):
    return int(-1 * n // 1 * -1)

def floor(n):
    return int(n // 1)
```

I used int() to make the values integer. As ceiling and floor are a type of rounding, I thought integer is the appropriate type to return.

The integer division //, goes to the next whole number to the left on the number line.  Therefore by using -1, I switch the direction around to get the ceiling, then use another * -1 to return to the original sign. The math is done from left to right.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old...but you can call those like this too:

```
>>> (3/2).__ceil__()
2
>>> (3/2).__floor__()
1
```

edit: this is for python 3.9 and above

Comment: This is cool, where can I find more information about this? Do all number objects have this dunder function?

Comment: All Real instances have this. You can see the numbers.Real docs: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Real)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
def ceil(n):
    res = int(n)
    return res if res == n or n < 0 else res+1

def floor(n):
    res = int(n)
    return res if res == n or n >= 0 else res-1
```

Comment: This `floor` definition is broken: it won't work correctly for negative integers.

Answer (score 0):

try it like:

```
if a%b != 0:
  print(int(a//b + 1))
else:
  print(int(a/b))
```