# Python round UP/DOWN integers in dictionary with list

Tags: python, rounding

Is there any method or easy way to round up integers to desired point(hundreds, thousands etc)? Yea, I know can use math lib, can use functions and etc, but seems very complicated for simple thing. At least old python version I couldnt find out something good.

```
13 -> 20;
2237 -> 2240;
3451 -> 3500
```

My situation:
`dict = {'Key':[2312, 467]}`

Need to get:
`dict = {'Key':[2320, 470]}`

Show you examples, also show when need to round down, or round in math way(0-4 to 0, 5-9 to 10)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round integers to the nearest 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348825/round-integers-to-the-nearest-10)

Comment: Is there any logic behind what rounds to the nearest hundred, and what rounds to the nearest ten?

Comment: Why is 13 --> 20 and not 10?

Comment: @Karina, dont understand question. Because have task where can be only bigger value rounded to 10.

Comment: @ddejohn I can have different numbers/values from tens to thousands and all must be rounded up to tens. Asked more widely than I need, just to have understanding how u r solving it.

Comment: @Justme4ever my bad, misread that part.

Comment: @Justme4ever if they're rounded to the nearest ten, then `3451` should round to `3460`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python round up integer to next hundred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866046/python-round-up-integer-to-next-hundred). It's about rounding up to the next hundred rather than the next 10, but it's the same in principle. tl;dr: just map each number `x` to `x + (-x) % 10`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ya, pretty solid. Overlooked. Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ceil and floor equivalent in Python 3 without Math module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558805/ceil-and-floor-equivalent-in-python-3-without-math-module)

This should do like what you want.

```
round_degree = 100
number = 2151


# Example rounding down to nearest 100
rounded_down = (number // round_degree) * round_degree
print(number, rounded_down )


# Example rounding up to nearest 100
rounded_up = -(-number // round_degree) * round_degree
print(number, rounded_up)
```

Comment: I am just looking for shortest possible option.

Comment: A single expression is about as short as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:-

```
D = {'Key1': [2312, 467], 'Key2': [123, 129]}

for k, v in D.items():
    D[k] = [int(round(_n, -1)) for _n in v]

print(D)
```

Comment: Before I have dict Im putting it in and I can slice to get last value and compared to 0, if lastNumber not 0  10-lastNumber  + numberValue.  So how to solve I know, but I am looking for elegant short option :).

Comment: I must apologise for presenting inelegant code. I promise not to do it again

Comment: Just a heads up, `dict` is the name of the built-in data type in Python. By using it as a variable name you're overwriting that type's constructor which is a bad idea.

Comment: Quite right @ddejohn - I took it from the original question without thinking. I've edited it now

Comment: @DarkKnight lol I can't stop laughing

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your version of round

```
def round(number, digits):
    mult = 10**(digits)
    val = int((number*mult)+0.5*(1 if number > 0 else -1))/mult 
    return val

for k, v in dict.items():
   dict[k] = [ round(number, -1) for number in v ]
```