# Integer division to next integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

As you may know, if you do:

```
>>> 11/2
# 5
```

And

```
>>> 11/2.0
# 5.5
```

I'd like to get 6 in this case. I tried with:

```
>>> 11//2
# 5
```

And

```
>>> 11//2.0
# 5.0
```

The last one gives the prev integer. I'd like to get the next integer.
Even is the result is like `x.1` I'd like to get `(x+1)`.

How can I do this?

Comment: @user2357112 - Why did you reopen this? It's a clear duplicate.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: That question is about rounding numbers that are already floating-point, but introducing floating-point numbers at all for a purely-integer operation like this may not be a good idea.

Comment: It's obvious that a floating-point number will be introduced automatically when necessary. Any floating-point number of `n.0` is equal to the integer `n`. The answers on that question are perfectly applicable.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I think that an _applicable answer_ does not mean _the same question_

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: `555555555555555555.0 != 555555555555555555`. Using floating-point for this just seems like asking for subtle rounding bugs down the line.

Comment: And "why does function foo not run unless I call it" isn't the same question as "why does function main not run unless I call it" isn't the same question, but it is the same answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a ceiling equivalent of // operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822184/is-there-a-ceiling-equivalent-of-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rounded_up = x // y + bool(x % y)
```

We add 1 if the division produces a nonzero remainder. This has the benefit of not introducing floating-point imprecision, so it'll be correct in extreme cases where `math.ceil` produces the wrong answer.

---

We can also perform the operation with floor division and two negations:

```
rounded_up = -(-x // y)
```

The floor of -x/y is the negative of the ceiling of x/y, so negating again produces the ceiling of x/y. Again, we avoid floating-point rounding error by performing all operations in integer arithmetic.

Comment: Nice solution using bool. Which cases math.ceil will produce a wrong answer?

Comment: @Gocht: Dividing `2**64+1` by `2`, for example.

Comment: I didn't know this about precission with floating numbers. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Generally more efficient than doing both modulus and division work, it's easy to convert floor division:

```
x // y
```

into `ceil` division (and unlike using `math.ceil`, it runs no risk of getting incorrect results due to floating point imprecision for large values):

```
(x + y - 1) // y
```

If `x` is exactly divisible by `y`, then adding `y - 1` changes nothing; the floor division makes the end result unchanged. If it's not evenly divisible, this increases it above the next multiple, getting you ceil division with only a single division operation instead of two (division is expensive; doing it twice is doubly expensive), and no floating point precision issues.

The above doesn't work for negative `y`, but there is a solution that does work for it (at the expense of appearing more magical):

```
-(-x // y)
```

By flipping the sign on `x` first, you change the rounding behavior to work in the opposite direction after flipping the sign again at the end. So for `x == 5` and `y == -2`, this second solution produces `-2` (the ceiling of `-2.5`) correctly. It's typically more efficient than the original solution, but it's not as obvious how it works, so I can't strictly recommend it over the clearer solution when the divisor is known to be positive.

Comment: This almost works, but it does the wrong thing when `y` is negative. For example, when `x` is 5 and `y` is -2, `(x + y - 1) // y` is -1, but the correct ceiling division result would have been -2.

Comment: @user2357112: Missed your comment back then, but I've added a solution that always works regardless of whether `y` is positive or negative (it's actually a more efficient solution, it's just a little magical looking).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil)

```
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(11/2.0)
6.0
>>>
```