# I want to get rounded int number in python?

Tags: python, math

I have a number 120 and I divided by 100. I am getting 1.2 but actually I want to get 2 only (not 2.0) in python without importing any lib.

Can any one help here???

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14822184/270986, but it's answered by the answers to that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `modulo` operator to know whether to round up the result:

```
120//100 + (1 if 120%100 else 0)
```

Comment: It is really very helpful.
 Thanks!

Comment: I'd be interested to know the reason for the downvote??? Are there some edge cases?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I find this unnecessarily branchy. `-(-x // y)` is my preferred way to do a "ceiling division" in Python.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Thanks, I didn't know that one. It's clearly better. You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in function `ceil()` to round `1.2` up to `2`, and the built-in `int` function to cast it to an integer:

```
In [3]: int(ceil(120/100.0))
Out[3]: 2
```

Comment: `ceil` is actually [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/math.html#math.ceil), so you would have to `import math`

Comment: Interesting - I can't work out why this works in my IDE (Enthought Canopy). I haven't imported `math`.....

Comment: @gtlambert: If you're working in the IPython console inside Canopy, then you're using PyLab mode, in which many array-handling and plotting primitives have already been preloaded. (And in that case, your `ceil` is actually `numpy.ceil` rather than `math.ceil`.)