# Slicing a word in half

Tags: python, slice, division

The task requires me to cut a word in half and reverse it. Without using the if statement.

However if it has an uneven amount of letters, the remaining letters must stick to the first half of the word. Not the second like python does automatically.

I succeeded in cutting the word in half and reverse it. I tried multiple things but until now I have not found a way to cut the letter and put it behind the first half.

If I used the name 'Boris' and run the program as it is, the output will be 'risBo' and I have to make it say 'isBor'

```
#input

woord = input("Geef een woord in : ") #here I ask the user to give a word

#verwerking

eerste_helft = woord[0:len(woord)//2] #I cut the first half

tweede_helft = woord[(len(woord)//2):] #and cut the second


#output

print(tweede_helft + eerste_helft) #here I reversed the two halves
```

Comment: Add some expected output as well?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: ```remaining letters must stick to the first half of the word. Not the second like python does automatically``` Please elaborate this with an example

Comment: ok
If I used the name 'Boris' and run the program as it is, the output will be 'risBo' and I have to make it say 'isBor'.

Comment: @YackiKawaii [edit] your question to add additional details so that people don't also have to go through the comments to understand your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a ceiling equivalent of // operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822184/is-there-a-ceiling-equivalent-of-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//` is the floor division operator. If you're dividing integers by two, this means it'll always round down. A quick-and-dirty way to make it round up instead is to just add one, before diving by two:

```
eerste_helft = woord[0:(len(woord) + 1)//2] #I cut the first half

tweede_helft = woord[(len(woord) + 1)//2:] #and cut the second
```

For example, `7 // 2` used to equal 3. Now it equals 4, because `(7 + 1) // 2 == 4`.

Even numbers don't change, because `8 // 2` and `(8 + 1) // 2` are both still equal to 4.

Comment: Wow, I thought I had to add a 1 somewhere but this I had not tried.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to take the upper value after dividing by two, you can use it like this:

```
half1 = word[:len(word)+(len(word)%2==1)]
half2 = word[len(word)+(len(word)%2==1):]
print (half2+half1)
```