# Integer division on integers that returns ceil integer

Tags: python, integer-division

When two integers are divided with the **`//`** integer operator, it returns the floor integer.

To have the ceil integer **Only With Integer Operators** (to avoid `math.ceil`), I wrote the following lambda function :

```
ceilint=lambda x, y: x//y+ (1 if x%y else 0)
```

It works, but I wonder (as I am a Python beginner), if it is the right way to do that (*n.b.* I am sure that operands are integers) or if a better solution exists.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a ceiling equivalent of // operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822184/is-there-a-ceiling-equivalent-of-operator-in-python). The second answer does not use math.ceil

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `math.ceil` function though?

Comment: @TomMcLean. Thanks a lot. It is a better solution than mine. Problem solved

Comment: @KonradRudolph. To avoid an import and to work only with integers

Comment: @Stef1611 It’s part of the standard library. Avoiding such an import is ill-advised. *Do* take advantage of the standard library at every turn, don’t roll your own solutions unless there’s a specific reason to do so.

Comment: And the built in functions like sort and ceil might actually be faster than the code you write, because they are coded directly in C, which is much much faster...

Comment: @Someone. Are you sure ? `%timeit (10 + (3-1)) // 3` : 11.5 ns, `%timeit 10//3 + (1 if 10%3 else 0) `: 37.8 ns and `%timeit math.ceil(10/3) `: 264 ns. I use python 3.8.10 and jupyter notebook 6.3.0

Comment: math.ceil is slower because it uses floating point math over integer math. However the difference is negligable for most use cases

Comment: It is slower in this senario because you are using only intergers and not floating point numbers, and also calling a function is slower than writing the code for it in the main file.....`%timeit 23 + 12` = `8.36 ns` but `def addit(x, y):   return x + y
%timeit addit(23, 12)` = `100 ns`