# Bitwise operations to produce power of two in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

In just intonation theory, a type of music theory, intervals between notes are expressed with rational numbers. Doubling a frequency with a 2:1 ratio brings it up an octave and a 1:1 ratio is no change; a unison. So if I have an interval *n* that is larger than an octave or smaller than a unison (it goes down), it is useful to 'justify' it. That is, to make 1 ≤ *n* ≤ 2. I've been doing this in Python with the following function:

```
def justify(n):
    return n / 2 ** floor( log(n,2) )
```

The actual function involves the fractions library, but this gets the job done with floats and ints. The log finds to what power of 2 *n* is and floor rounds it down so that the resulting divisor is the nearest power of 2 below *n*. I've also tried this:

```
def justify(n):
    return n / int( '1'.ljust( len( bin(n) ) - 2, '0' ), 2 )
```

This one just take the length of the binary representation and pads zeroes based on that. Of course, that only works with ints. I was wondering if there is any way to perform this operation with bitwise operations. It seems like the binary would lend itself well to the power of 2 operation. At minimum, I would like to see a way to replace `2 ** floor( log(n,2) )` with something bitwise. Extra points if it can handle floats, but I understand that's more complicated.

Comment: I guess you want to have something like that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322510/given-an-integer-how-do-i-find-the-next-largest-power-of-two-using-bit-twiddlin

Comment: You could do `while n > 2: n = n/2` followed by `while n < 1; n = n*2`. It's not bitwise or O(1), but it does work for integers and floats and fractions. Just don't try to justify anything less than or equal to zero.

Comment: For integers, look into the `bit_length` method:  https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length.  Specifically, you can replace `2**floor(log(n, 2))` with `1 << (n.bit_length() - 1)`.

Comment: The base 2 logarithm of an integer is equivalent to the position of its highest bit set. It's possible to find this in O(log_2(n)) operations for an n-bit integer, but I suspect that the complicated bit twiddling involved will be slower than the built-in functions–lots of work done at the Python level rather than native code.

Comment: ... and BTW, for floats you want `math.frexp`: `2 * math.frexp(x)[0]` will give the 'justified' value of a float `x`.

Comment: It looks like `2*frexp(n)[0]` works best for floats and `n / (1<<(n.bit_length()-1))` works best for ints. This will really optimize some of my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For integers only, you can get there in a slightly devious way with the following:

```
def justify(n):
    return n / 1<<(n.bit_length()-1)
```

I've no idea if it's faster without significant testing but a quick test with `timeit` shows it to be about twice as fast as your first snippet.

However, converting `n` to a float in the numerator (to get a float return) slows it to the same speed as your original.

```
def justify(n):
    return float(n) / 1<<(n.bit_length()-1)
```

`bit_length` gives the minimum number of bits required to represent `abs(x)` which is actually going to be one more than you want for your calculation.

I would expect `log(n,2)` to be heavily optimized for powers of two in the base - and it's implemented in C. So you will have trouble beating it.

Possibly changing the denominator to `1<<int(log(n,2))` may give you better performance than the `2**` approach .. and it seems to be about 30% faster giving

```
def justify(n):
    return float(n) / (1<<int(log(n,2)))
```

It is possible to do it completely with bitwise operators:

```
def justify_bitwise(n):
   int_n = int(abs(n))
   p = 0
   while int_n != 1:
       p += 1
       int_n >>= 1

   return float(n) / (1<<p)
```

But `timeit` clocks this at 2.16 microseconds. An order of magnitude slower than using `bit_length`

Comment: No need for this deviousness.  Use the `bit_length` method!  (Assuming Python 2.7 or Python 3, that is.)

Comment: You want `n.bit_length()`, not `int.bit_length(n)`.  And I'd be quite surprised if `int(log(n, 2))` were faster than `n.bit_length() - 1`.  On my machine, it's about a factor of 4 slower, but YMMV.

Comment: `int.bit_length(n)` works too. And yes, it's the `1<<` vs the `2**` approach which seems to give an advantage. `timeit` gives 301ns for `2**int.bit_length(1234)` and 207ns for `1<<int.bit_length(1234)`

Comment: Yes, of course `int.bit_length(n)` works; it's just a peculiar way to call a method on an instance. :-)  Do you also write `list.append(my_list, value)` rather than `my_list.append(value)` to append a value to a list?

Comment: I was mucking around in ipython, and `1234.bit_length()` didn't work .. so, cut'n' paste :)

Comment: Note also that in Python 2.7, `int.bit_length(n)` fails when `n` has type `long`.

Answer (score 3):

`math.frexp(x)`, as Mark Dickinson pointed out in the question comments, is the way to go:

```
def justify(n):
    return 2*frexp(n)[0]
```

It works with floats as well as integers.