# Determining Powers of 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm, math

I am creating a simple bracket system and I need a way to check if there are a correct number of teams, OR if my program needs to compensate for bye rounds.

Right now, I am checking for "powers of two" with this function:

```
function validBracket(data) {
    var x = data.teams.length;
    return ((x != 0) && !(x & (x - 1)));
}
```

This works pretty well, but I am needing to know how many Bye rounds to add.
For instance, if I had `16 teams`, I would not need to add anymore teams. However, if I had `12 teams`, I would need the first `4 teams` to get a bye round.

**How can I calculate number of bye rounds to add to my bracket? And would hard-coding an array of powers of two be better?**

In pseudo code, something like this is what i was thinking of:

```
if(validateBracket(data)) {
    // Valid number of teams (power of two). Keep going.
} else {
    var byeRounds = calculateByeRounds();
}
```

**NOTE:** I would rather not use an array of powers of two like below:

`var powersOfTwo = [2,4,8,16,32,...];`

The reasoning behind this is that I would be limiting the number of teams that could be put in the system (however, I don't think a person would have over 256 teams).

Comment: Calculate the next power of 2 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322510/given-an-integer-how-do-i-find-the-next-largest-power-of-two-using-bit-twiddlin) and subtract from your current integer

Comment: Hint: Each match eliminates one player. So a tournament of 12 players requires 11 matches. Tournaments are easy to design for powers of two, so make 12 players up to 16 by introducing 4 fictitious opponents. These are the byes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var needed = (1 << Math.ceil(Math.log2(n))) - n;
```

More generalized solution for extreme cases:

```
var needed = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log2(n))) - n;
```

Comment: Very simplistic. Instead of my first function, I can check if this returns `0` then it is a perfect bracket. Thanks!

Comment: Not that this matters in this particular context but this binary logic has an upper boundary. This breaks if ``n > Math.pow(2, 30)``.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Why is this the case? Considering there will not be that many teams I assume it's ok. I would still llke to know the reasoning behind why it fails though.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: True. In case OP has more than `1073741824` teams, he should substitute `(1 << ...)` with `Math.pow(2, ...)`. OP, the reason is that `1 << 31` is a negative number, and `1 << 32` is `1`, owing to `<<` being defined on the JavaScript's almost nonexistent integer type.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const n = 2;
// Convert n to binary representation as a string and count the number of '1' characters
  
const count = n.toString(2).split('').filter(bit => bit === '1').length;
  
// Return true if there is exactly one '1' bit in the binary representation of n
 
const result = count === 1 ? `${n} is power of two` : `${n} is NOT power of two`;
 
console.log(result);
```