# Previous power of 2

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

There is a lot of information on how to find the next power of 2 of a given value (see refs) but I cannot find any to get the previous power of two.

The only way I find so far is to keep a table with all power of two up to 2^64 and make a simple lookup.

- [Acius' Snippets](http://acius2.blogspot.com/2007/11/calculating-next-power-of-2.html)
- [gamedev](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=229831)
- [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightMultLookup)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364985/algorithm-for-finding-the-smallest-power-of-two-thats-greater-or-equal-to-a-give)

Comment: Get the next power of 2, and divide by 2...?

Comment: Get the next one, divide by 2.

Comment: This should be a pretty straightforward adaptation of the existing algorithms you linked. Can you post what you have and we can help you along with hints?

Comment: He's asking for the power of two that's *closest to a given value* (and less than, not greater than the given value)

Comment: clear all but the most significant bit. it is a general recipe, you can implemented in multiple ways

Comment: @Michael - Thanks, that makes this question make a *lot* more sense.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

This is my current solution to find the next and previous powers of two of any given positive integer n and also a small function to determine if a number is power of two.

This implementation is for Ruby.

```
class Integer

  def power_of_two?
    (self & (self - 1) == 0)
  end

  def next_power_of_two
    return 1 if self <= 0
    val = self
    val = val - 1
    val = (val >> 1) | val
    val = (val >> 2) | val
    val = (val >> 4) | val
    val = (val >> 8) | val
    val = (val >> 16) | val
    val = (val >> 32) | val if self.class == Bignum
    val = val + 1
  end

  def prev_power_of_two
   return 1 if self <= 0
   val = self
   val = val - 1
   val = (val >> 1) | val
   val = (val >> 2) | val
   val = (val >> 4) | val
   val = (val >> 8) | val
   val = (val >> 16) | val
   val = (val >> 32) | val if self.class == Bignum
   val = val - (val >> 1)
  end
end
```

Example use:

```
10.power_of_two? => false
16.power_of_two? => true
10.next_power_of_two => 16
10.prev_power_of_two => 8
```

For the previous power of two, finding the next and dividing by two is slightly slower than the method above.

I am not sure how it works with Bignums.

Comment: Hey, etiquette has it that you should have awarded the answer to the guy who gave you the idea in the first place. I think it is bad form to award yourself the right answer in this case.

Comment: Do the marked answer gives something to the poster? I thought the marked answer should be the most useful to others with the same question. This one summarizes the whole discussion in a single easy to understand answer.

Answer (score 41):

From [Hacker's Delight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654), a nice *branchless* solution:

```
uint32_t flp2 (uint32_t x)
{
    x = x | (x >> 1);
    x = x | (x >> 2);
    x = x | (x >> 4);
    x = x | (x >> 8);
    x = x | (x >> 16);
    return x - (x >> 1);
}
```

This typically takes 12 instructions. You can do it in fewer if your CPU has a "count leading zeroes" instruction.

Comment: FWIW, this is significantly faster than the `bsr` solution for AMD CPUs, 3-4x faster for 32-bit version and 1.5-2x for 64-bit version.  I've heard it's the opposite for Intel but I do not have access to their CPUs to test.

Comment: Note this doesn't return the previous power of 2 if the input is a power of two. For example if x=16, it returns 16. To solve this add `x--;` as the first line.

Comment: @Roxerio: Depends which AMD you test with.  On K8, `bsr` was disastrously slow, like 28 uops with 10c latency and throughput.  On K10 and Bulldozer, it's 7 uops with 3 or 4c throughput and latency. About the same on Zen 1 through 3, but single-uop with 0.25c throughput on Zen 4, 1c latency!  (https://uops.info/).  Intel has fast `bsr` and fast `lzcnt`. 
 `lzcnt` is fast on all AMD CPUs that have it, though, even faster than on Intel.  So if you're compiling with `-march=x86-64-v3` (AVX2+FMA+BMI2), you can count on fast `std::countl_zero`

Comment: @makeworld: That would make `x=0` return `2147483648`, which might be less desirable.  Or won't matter if your use-case never has zeros as inputs.  or if the current behaviour is what you want, just name it something that doesn't include "previous power of 2".

Answer (score 5):

```
uint32_t previous_power_of_two( uint32_t x ) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    // x--; Uncomment this, if you want a strictly less than 'x' result.
    x |= (x >> 1);
    x |= (x >> 2);
    x |= (x >> 4);
    x |= (x >> 8);
    x |= (x >> 16);
    return x - (x >> 1);
}
```

Thanks for the responses. I will try to sum them up and explain a little bit clearer.
What this algorithm does is changing to 'ones' all bits after the first 'one' bit, cause these are the only bits that can make our 'x' larger than its previous power of two.
After making sure they are 'ones', it just removes them, leaving the first 'one' bit intact. That single bit in its place is our previous power of two.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one liner for posterity (ruby):

```
2**Math.log(input, 2).floor(0)
```

Comment: He listed the question under "algorithm", so I gave a solution that is algorithm oriented.

Comment: This was exactly the information I hoped to find when I googled "nearest power of 2" and found this StackOverflow question.

Comment: Does Ruby's `log` implementation guarantee that the result is exact for powers of two?  If not, it could be slightly below the exact result so `floor` rounds all the way down.  I wouldn't use FP math for this, at least not math library functions that aren't required by IEEE-754 to produce correctly-rounded results.

Comment: If `Math.log(input, 2)` avoids conversion to natural-log and back, it might be safe.  The usual implementation strategy for log is to extract the exponent field from the bit-pattern and add the result of a polynomial over the mantissa.  (This is the part you want floor to discard.  Using int to FP conversion and just extracting the exponent field from the FP bit-pattern (after type-punning it back to integer) is a known way to find the position of the leading `1` bit.)  If the polynomial approximation is exactly 0 for a mantissa of 0 (representing 1.0), and doesn't go negative for small pos...

Answer (score 5):

The `g++` compiler provides a builtin function `__builtin_clz` that counts leading zeros:

So we could do:

```cpp
int previousPowerOfTwo(unsigned int x) {
  return 1 << (sizeof(x)*8 - 1) - __builtin_clz(x);
}

int main () {
  std::cout << previousPowerOfTwo(7)  << std::endl;
  std::cout << previousPowerOfTwo(31) << std::endl;
  std::cout << previousPowerOfTwo(33) << std::endl;
  std::cout << previousPowerOfTwo(8)  << std::endl;
  std::cout << previousPowerOfTwo(91) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
4
16
32
8
64
```

But note that, for `x == 0`, `__builtin_clz` return is undefined.

Comment: In C++20, use `std::countl_zero` from `#include <bit>`, which is well-defined for input=0, producing the bit-width of the input.  e.g. 32 for `uint32_t`.  So it's slightly slower than `__builtin_clz` on older x86 where it has to check for zero around using `bsr`, but full-speed if it can compile to `lzcnt` which has the same semantics for input = 0.

Comment: Naming: this returns powers of 2 unchanged, so it's actually implementing `round_down_to_pow2`, not always the previous.

Comment: The return type should be `unsigned`.  It makes more sense to return unsigned `2147483648` than int `-2147483648` for an input of UINT_MAX.  I was playing around with some versions that use `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` instead of assuming CHAR_BIT=8 and not padding, as well as being safe for all inputs, or not since that can be slower.  https://godbolt.org/z/Mrs38vPr3

Comment: Oh, in C++20 there's `std::bit_floor` which does the whole thing (and returns `0` for input=0). 
 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_floor .  libstdc++'s implementation isn't as efficient as mine, at least on x86 when `lzcnt` is available.  libc++'s compiles well with clang: https://godbolt.org/z/drK9KE7sf

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest approach (for positive numbers):

```java
// find next (must be greater) power, and go one back
p = 1; while (p <= n) p <<= 1; p >>= 1;
```

You can make variations in many ways if you want to optimize.

Comment: Fails for fixed-width integer types if the highest bit is set.  Then you'll shift out the high bit, leaving 0.  e.g. for `n = UINT_MAX`, there is no `unsigned p` such that `p <= n` is false, let alone a power of 2.  You could check for `p <= (n>>1)`, because `n>>1` has an MSB of 0 (after a logical right shift.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the next-higher power of 2, the next-lower power of 2 is either that next-higher or half that. It depends on what you consider to be the "next higher" for any power of 2 (and what you consider to be the next-lower power of 2).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if (tt = v >> 16)
{
   r = (t = tt >> 8) ? 0x1000000 * Table256[t] : 0x10000 * Table256[tt];
}
else 
{
  r = (t = v >> 8) ? 0x100 * Table256[t] : Table256[v];
}
```

It is just modified method from http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup.
This require like 7 operations and it might be faster to replace multiplications whit shift.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with bit manipulation only:

```
long FindLargestPowerOf2LowerThanN(long n)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(n > 0);

    byte digits = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        n >>= 1;
        digits++;
    }                            

    return 1 << (digits - 1);
}
```

Example:

```
FindLargestPowerOf2LowerThanN(6):
Our Goal is to get 4 or 100
1) 6 is 110
2) 110 has 3 digits
3) Since we need to find the largest power of 2 lower than n we subtract 1 from digits
4) 1 << 2 is equal to 100 

FindLargestPowerOf2LowerThanN(132):
Our Goal is to get 128 or 10000000
1) 6 is 10000100
2) 10000100 has 8 digits
3) Since we need to find the largest power of 2 lower than n we subtract 1 from digits
4) 1 << 7 is equal to 10000000
```

Answer (score 0):

For C language, the `stdc_bit_floor()` series of APIs would be introduced in the C23 standard. There are a type-generic version (`stdc_bit_floor()` macro) and type-specific versions (`stdc_bit_floor_*()`) defined in the header `<stdbit.h>`. In the near future this will be the standard way to round integers to a power of 2.

[The latest draft of the C23 standard (N3096)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf)

For C++, C++20 has [std::bit_floor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_floor) which does the exact same thing.

Both `stdc_bit_floor(x)` and `std::bit_floor(x)` are required to return `0` if the input value `x` is zero.

---

If your compiler and C library do not support C23 yet, here is an implementation that I consider it an "ultimate" solution. I intended the library writers to copy this code and adapt appropriately.

The following code

- is targeted for C language (not C++),
- uses compiler built-ins to yield efficient code ([CLZ or BSR instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set)) if compiler supports any,
- is portable (standard C and no assembly) with the exception of built-ins, and
- addresses undefined behavior of the compiler built-ins (when `x` is zero).

```c
#include <limits.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
# if _MSC_VER >= 1400
/* _BitScanReverse is introduced in Visual C++ 2005 and requires
   <intrin.h> (also introduced in Visual C++ 2005). */
#include <intrin.h>
#pragma intrinsic(_BitScanReverse)
#pragma intrinsic(_BitScanReverse64)
#  define HAVE_BITSCANREVERSE 1
# endif
#endif

/* Macro indicating that the compiler supports __builtin_clz().
   The name HAVE_BUILTIN_CLZ seems to be the most common, but in some
   projects HAVE__BUILTIN_CLZ is used instead. */
#ifdef __has_builtin
# if __has_builtin(__builtin_clz)
#  define HAVE_BUILTIN_CLZ 1
# endif
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
# if (__GNUC__ > 3)
#  define HAVE_BUILTIN_CLZ 1
# elif defined(__GNUC_MINOR__)
#  if (__GNUC__ == 3 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 4)
#   define HAVE_BUILTIN_CLZ 1
#  endif
# endif
#endif


unsigned int stdc_bit_floor_ui(unsigned int x);
unsigned long stdc_bit_floor_ul(unsigned long x);
unsigned long long stdc_bit_floor_ull(unsigned long long x);

/**
 * Returns the largest power of two that is not greater than x. If x
 * is 0, returns 0.
 */
unsigned int stdc_bit_floor_ui(unsigned int x)
{
#ifdef HAVE_BITSCANREVERSE
    if (x <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        unsigned long int index;
        (void) _BitScanReverse(&index, x);
        return (1U << index);
    }
#elif defined(HAVE_BUILTIN_CLZ)
    if (x <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (1U << (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1 - __builtin_clz(x)));
#else
    /* Fastest known solution without compiler built-ins or integer
       logarithm instructions.
       From the book "Hacker's Delight".
       Converted to a loop for smaller code size.
       ("gcc -O3" will unroll this.) */
    {
        unsigned int shift;
        for (shift = 1; shift < sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT; shift <<= 1) {
            x |= (x >> shift);
        }
    }
    return (x - (x >> 1));
#endif
}

/**
 * Returns the largest power of two that is not greater than x. If x
 * is 0, returns 0.
 */
unsigned long stdc_bit_floor_ul(unsigned long x)
{
#ifdef HAVE_BITSCANREVERSE
    if (x <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        unsigned long index;
        (void) _BitScanReverse(&index, x);
        return (1UL << index);
    }
#elif defined(HAVE_BUILTIN_CLZ)
    if (x <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (1UL << (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1 - __builtin_clzl(x)));
#else
    {
        unsigned int shift;
        for (shift = 1; shift < sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT; shift <<= 1) {
            x |= (x >> shift);
        }
    }
    return (x - (x >> 1));
#endif
}

/**
 * Returns the largest power of two that is not greater than x. If x
 * is 0, returns 0.
 */
unsigned long long stdc_bit_floor_ull(unsigned long long x)
{
#if (defined(HAVE_BITSCANREVERSE) && \
    ULLONG_MAX == 18446744073709551615ULL)
    if (x <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        /* assert(sizeof(__int64) == sizeof(long long)); */
        unsigned long int index;
        (void) _BitScanReverse64(&index, x);
        return (1ULL << index);
    }
#elif defined(HAVE_BUILTIN_CLZ)
    if (x <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (1ULL << (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1 - __builtin_clzll(x)));
#else
    {
        unsigned int shift;
        for (shift = 1; shift < sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT; shift <<= 1) {
            x |= (x >> shift);
        }
    }
    return (x - (x >> 1));
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a count leading zeros function (a.k.a. bitscan right), determining the next lowest power of 2 is easy:

```
uint32_t lower_power_of_2(uint32_t x) {
  assert(x != 0);
  return 1 << (31 - __builtin_clz(x));
}
```

Here, `__builtin_clz` is recognized by gcc and clang. Use `_BitScanReverse` with a Microsoft compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way:

```
//n is the number you want to find the previus power of 2
long m = 1;
while(n > 1){
    n >>= 1;
    m <<= 1;
}
//m is the previous power of two
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in one line.

```
int nextLowerPowerOf2 = i <= 0
                        ? 0
                        : ((i & (~i + 1)) == i)
                            ? i >> 1
                            : (1 << (int)Math.Log(i, 2));
```

result

```
i    power_of_2
-2    0
-1    0
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    4
6    4
7    4
8    4
9    8
```

Here's a more readable version in c#, with the <=0 guard clause distributed to the utility methods.

```
int nextLowerPowerOf2 = IsPowerOfTwo(i) 
    ? i >> 1 // shift it right
    : GetPowerOfTwoLessThanOrEqualTo(i);

public static int GetPowerOfTwoLessThanOrEqualTo(int x)
{
    return (x <= 0 ? 0 : (1 << (int)Math.Log(x, 2)));
}

public static bool IsPowerOfTwo(int x)
{
    return (((x & (~x + 1)) == x) && (x > 0));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you work in base 2, you can jump from a power of two to the next one by just adding or removing a digit from the right.

For instance,  the previous power of two of the number 8 is the number 4.  In binary:

01000  ->  0100     (we remove the trailing zero to get number 4)

So the algorithm to solve the calculus of the previous power of two is:

previousPower := number shr 1

previousPower = number >> 1

(or any other syntax)

Comment: This is only true if `number` is also a power of 2. If `number` is say 11, then this wont work.

Answer (score -2):

Below code will find the previous power of 2:

```
int n = 100;
    n /= 2;//commenting this will gives the next power of 2
    n |= n>>1;
    n |= n>>2;
    n |= n>>4;
    n |= n>>16;

System.out.println(n+1);
```

Comment: Other answers are very similar, and this one return wrong results if n is a power of 2 already.