# Getting Position of the Leftmost Bit

Tags: objective-c, binary, bit-manipulation

I have a 5 bit integer that I'm working with.  Is there a native function in Objective-C that will let me know which bit is the leftmost?

i.e. I have 01001, it would return 8 or the position.

Comment: Do you mean the leftmost bit that is 1? It looks like it from your example, but...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSInteger value = 9;
NSInteger shift = 1;
for(NSInteger bit = value; bit > 1; bit = value >> ++shift);
NSInteger leftmostbit = 1 << shift;
```

Works for every number of bits.

Comment: Don't use `pow` for this.  There's no language guarantee that `pow` will deliver an accurate power of two (it happens to on OS X, which is probably what's being targeted since the question is tagged `objective-c`, but it's not a portable assumption).  It's also grossly inefficient on many platforms.  You want `leftmostbit = 1 << shift`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I updated the code based on your comment.

Answer (score 7):

You can build a lookup table, with 32 elements: 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: A 32 element lookup table is far and away the best solution for this particular case.

Comment: @Stephen: only if you are 100% certain that the number of bits will **always** be 5 (or at least a relatively small number), and that you never want to do any optimisations, e.g. SIMD or GPGPU.

Comment: @Paul R: Actually, a 32-byte lookup table is perfect for SIMD implementation on most vector architectures (On AltiVec or NEON it's a single instruction; SSE takes a little bit more work, but still isn't too bad).  GPGPU may be another story, as you note.

Comment: @Stephen: true, this works well on AltiVec with vec_perm, but it gets ugly if you need to go beyond a 32 element LUT. It's much harder on SSE, unless you can assume SSSE3 (and hence PSHUFB).

Answer (score 6):

This is effectively the same operation as counting he number of leading 0s. Some CPUs have an instruction for this, otherwise you can use tricks such as those found in [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/).

It's also equivalent to rounding down to the nearest power of 2, and again you can find efficient methods for doing this in [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/), e.g.

```
uint8_t flp2(uint8_t x)
{
    x = x | (x >> 1);
    x = x | (x >> 2);
    x = x | (x >> 4);
    return x - (x >> 1);
}
```

See also: [Previous power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679815/previous-power-of-2)

Comment: `x |= x >> 1` will do as well. Great solution!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a table lookup, I would use `31 - __builtin_clz(yourNumber)`.

`__builtin_clz( )` is a compiler intrinsic supported by gcc, llvm-gcc, and clang (and possibly other compilers as well).  It returns the number of leading zero bits in an integer argument.  Subtracting that from `31` gives you the position of the highest-order set bit.  It should generate reasonably fast code on any target architecture.

Answer (score 1):

[Stanford Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) have lots of examples of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the value of whatever bit is in position five from the right (the "leftmost" of a five-bit value), then:

```
    int value = 17;
    int bit = (value >> 4) & 1; // bit is 1
```

If you mean the position of the leftmost bit that is 1:

```
    int value = 2;
    int position;
    for (position = 0; position < 5; position++) {
            int bit = (value >> position) & 1;
            if (bit == 1)
                    break;
    }
    // position is 1
```

Position will be 0 for the bit furthest to the right, 4 for the leftmost bit of your five-bit value, or 5 if all bits where zero.

Note: this is not the most effective solution, in clock cycles. It is hopefully a reasonably clear and educational one. :)

Answer (score 0):

To clear all bits below the most significant bit:

```
while ( x & (x-1) ) x &= x - 1;
// 01001 => 01000
```

To clear all bits above the least significant bit:

```
x &= -x;
// 01001 => 00001
```

To get the position of the only set bit in a byte:

```
position = ((0x56374210>>(((((x)&-(x))*0x17)>>3)&0x1C))&0x07);
// 01000 => 3
```

In libkern.h there is a `clz` function defined to count leading zeros in a 32 bit int.  That is the closest thing to a native Objective-C function.  To get the position of the most significant bit in an int:

```
position = 31 - clz( x );
// 01001 => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

With VC++ have a look at
_BitScanReverse/(64) in

Answer (score -1):

I don't know objective C but this is how I would do it in C.

pow(2, int(log2(Number))

This should give you the left most 1 bit value.

PLEASE SEE STEPHEN CANON'S COMMENT BELOW BEFORE USING THIS SOLUTION.

Comment: This is incredibly slow on many platforms, and will give you the wrong answer on others (there's no guarantee that the `log2` or `pow` functions are correctly rounded -- even for small integers -- and on many platforms they are not).

Comment: @Stephen Canon - I just wanted to show one other method of solving this issue. You may be right on the slow issue but the whole idea of int casting is to get rid of the fraction part and once you do that pow() will always return you whole numbers. I am not aware that log2 and pow have rounding issues. If that is the case then the results can go wrong.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `pow(2, someInteger)` will always return a whole number.  In fact, I have had the misfortune of using several platforms on which it did not (unfortunate, but true).