# What is fastest method to calculate a number having only bit set which is the most significant digit set in another number?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Previous power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679815/previous-power-of-2)
>   [Getting the Leftmost Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893525/getting-the-leftmost-bit)

What I want is, suppose there is a number `5` i.e. `101`. My answer should be `100`. For `9` i.e. `1001`, the answer should be `1000`

Comment: I changed your binary representations to match the decimal ones (both were wrong), and changed one of the decimal ones; hopefully it's now what you intended to say, I wasn't positive

Comment: See previous questions which are virtually identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679815/previous-power-of-2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893525/getting-the-leftmost-bit

Comment: Wow, that is some impressive cleanup. Assuming you got it right, you managed to turn this question from incomprehensible to well asked. Of course, it's still a dupe.

Comment: Against closing: This is IMHO a question about **performance** and **machine dependend optimization**, not how to do it.

Comment: why are all of these questions closed? there is an answer that only applies to c++ here!

Answer (score 7):

You can't ask for the **fastest** sequence without giving constrains on the **machine on which this has to run**. For example, some machines support an instruction called "count leading zeroes" or have means to emulate it very quickly. If you can access this instruction (for example with gcc) then you can write:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t f(uint32_t x) 
{
    return ((uint64_t)1)<<(32-__builtin_clz(x)-1);
}
int main()
{
    printf("=>%d\n",f(5));
    printf("=>%d\n",f(9));
}
```

f(x) returns what you want (the least y with x>=y and y=2**n). The compiler will now generate the optimal code sequence for the target machine. For example, when compiling for a default x86_64 architecture, f() looks like this:

```
    bsrl    %edi, %edi
    movl    $31, %ecx
    movl    $1, %eax
    xorl    $31, %edi
    subl    %edi, %ecx
    salq    %cl, %rax
    ret
```

You see, no loops here! 7 instructions, no branches.

But if I tell my compiler (gcc-4.5) to optimize for the machine I'm using right now (AMD Phenom-II), then this comes out for f():

```
    bsrl    %edi, %ecx
    movl    $1, %eax
    salq    %cl, %rax
    ret
```

This is probably the fastest way to go for this machine.

**EDIT:** f(0) would have resulted in UB, I've fixed that (and the assembly). Also, uint32_t means that I can write 32 without feeling guilty :-)

Comment: You're relying on a very platform specific assembly instruction, but bothering to use compatibility for machines with 7 or 9 bit chars? (`CHAR_BIT`)? :P (But +1 though)

Comment: IIRC, then all recent versions of gcc have __builtin_clz(x), so basically this code should be fine for all machines with gcc support.

Comment: Well, CHAR_BIT is a nice hint why this 8 is an 8. Just dropping the 8 in there would have made the code less clear. :oP indeed.

Comment: Rather than `(uint64_t)1`, you could write `1ULL`.

Comment: "f(0) would have resulted in UB, I've fixed that"  The code still contains UB, because __builtin_ctz is undefined for 0.

Answer (score 6):

From [Hacker's Delight](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0-201-91465-4/38), a nice branchless solution:

```
uint32_t flp2 (uint32_t x)
{
    x = x | (x >> 1);
    x = x | (x >> 2);
    x = x | (x >> 4);
    x = x | (x >> 8);
    x = x | (x >> 16);
    return x - (x >> 1);
}
```

This typically takes 12 instructions. You can do it in fewer if your CPU has a "count leading zeroes" instruction.

Comment: It is better if you just vote to close as exact duplicate... instead of adding yet the same answer again.

Comment: @David: I would have done if I'd had any close votes left for today. As it is I posted links to two duplicates in the comments above, assuming that others would vote to close.

Answer (score 4):

```
int input = 5;
std::size_t numBits = 0;
while(input)
{
    input >>= 1;
    numBits++;
}
int output = 1 << (numBits-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a task related to the bit counting. [Check this out.](http://gurmeetsingh.wordpress.com/2008/08/05/fast-bit-counting-routines/)

Using the 2a (which is my favorite of the algorithms; not the fastest) one can come up with this:

```
int highest_bit_mask (unsigned int n)  {
   while (n)  {
      if (n & (n-1)) {
         n &= (n-1) ;
      } else {
         return n;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The magic of  `n &= (n-1);` is that it removes from `n` the least significant bit. (Corollary: `n & (n-1)` is false only when `n` has precisely one bit set.) The algorithm complexity depends on number of bits set in the input.

Check out the link anyway. It is a very amusing and enlightening read which might give you more ideas.