# Clear all but the most significant one bit

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

For an unsigned integer `j`, the operation `j&(-j)` clears all but the *least* significant 1 bit, where `-j` is the negative of `j` treating `j` as a signed integer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set

Is there a similar simple operation that clears all but the *most* significant 1 bit?

An obvious solution is using `clz` (count leading zeros) operation which is present in nearly all contemporary processors. There is also a question [Previous power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679815/previous-power-of-2) with an answer that is said to work even faster than `clz` on old AMD processors. See also [What is fastest method to calculate a number having only bit set which is the most significant digit set in another number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407070/what-is-fastest-method-to-calculate-a-number-having-only-bit-set-which-is-the-mo)

My question is whether there is something simpler than using `clz` which may not be easily accessible in certain languages. Note that I need the most significant 1 bit itself, not its position (logarithm).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Previous power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679815/previous-power-of-2)

Comment: @NateEldredge I cannot see how my question may duplicate the question on the "Previous power of two". And there is clearly no answer to my question.

Comment: "Clear all but most significant 1 bit" is equivalent to "round down to a power of two", which is what the answers to that question do.  Try them out and see.  The fact that none of them is "similarly simple" to `j&(-j)` suggests that nobody knows of such a simple algorithm for this.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have edited my question according to your remark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is fastest method to calculate a number having only bit set which is the most significant digit set in another number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407070/what-is-fastest-method-to-calculate-a-number-having-only-bit-set-which-is-the-mo)

Comment: [What is the fastest way to get the power of 2 less than a certain number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25220184/995714), [What is the fastest/most efficient way to find the highest set bit (msb) in an integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671815/995714)

Comment: @phuclv I need the most significant 1 bit itself, not its position (logarithm). Of course, if one has the position then that bit is obtained by bit shift. But nonexistence of a "simple" formula for the position does not imply the nonexistence for the bit itself, as it is the case for the least significant set bit.

Comment: @phuclv I have added the link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407070/what-is-fastest-method-to-calculate-a-number-having-only-bit-set-which-is-the-mo

Comment: in any case there were already tons of duplicate questions of yours. And *simpler* is too broad, just like "fastest". Speed depends on the compiler and the platform, and simplicity depends on the view of the reader

Answer (score 1):

For locate position of highest "1" in the word, I am using BSR assembly operation:

```
static inline uint32_t bsr(uint32_t x) {
  uint32_t rc = 0;
  __asm__("bsr %1,%0":"=r" (rc):"rm" (x));
  return rc;
}
```

It returns position of highest "1". For example, bsr(5) == 2.
if needed this code for 64-bit "x", use **bsrq** instruction.