# How to convert signal from Time domain to Frequency domain with Java

Tags: java, signal-processing, fft

I have one signal y. The signal gets values from 0 to 1. The signal is actually derived from the red channel (from RGB) from a smartphone's camera, normalized by mapping all values from the space [0,1,... 255] to the space [0 - 1] by dividing by 255.
I have another array x for storing the camera frames 0,1,2,3,... 
What I want to do is to convert the signal y from time domain to the frequency domain using Java. I have tried to use the class provided [here](https://gist.github.com/saiday/f238fd4f414c2e4ee91f2f77c0a34a6d/revisions).

My code is

```
fftsize = powtwo(y.size()); //keep samples of a size of power of 2
Float[] rp = new Float[fftsize]; //rp is real part of signal (= y)
for(int i=0; i<fftsize; i++){
    rp[i]=y.get(i);
}

Float[] ip = new Float[fftsize]; //ip is the imaginary part of signal = 0
for(int i=0; i<fftsize;i++){
    ip[i]=0.0f;
}
fft(rp,ip);
```

where

```
public int powtwo(int size){  //this function estimates the next power of 2 (below the given int value).
while(!(Math.sqrt((double)size)-(int)Math.sqrt((double)size) == 0)){
    size--;
}
return size;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right and I don't know the next steps for turning FFT to frequency domain signal.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have started off OK, apart from the fact that `powtwo` is horribly inefficient. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2679815/253056) for various alternatives which are much more efficient.)

The FFT you are using is "in-place", so the frequency domain real/imaginary parts are returned in the input arrays. What you do with this data depends on your specific requirements, e.g. if you want to generate a power spectrum (one of the most common uses of an FFT) you would do something like this:

```
// ...

fft(rp,ip);

Float[] spectrum = new Float[fftsize / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < fftsize / 2; i++)
{
    spectrum[i] = Math.sqrt(rp[i] * rp[i] + ip[i] * ip[i]);
}
```