# normalize floating point

Tags: assembly, mips, normalization, mars-simulator

i am doing floating point addition using MARS.

```
  SameExponent:
  add $s6,$s4,$s5
```

after I aligned the exponents, I added up the significands,but how do I detect if the sum is still normalized or not in order to shift the signicicand to the left or right? Thank you

Comment: Is this the MARS MIPS simulator? If so you might want to tag it with mips as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the significands are integers in the range -A ... +A, then the result of adding them together is in the range -2A ... +2A. To normalize the result you need to shift left or right to get the most-significant 1 bit back to the normalized position, keeping track of how much you shifted so you can adjust the exponent accordingly.

The maximum required right shift is one position; the left shift can be more if your arguments may be positive or negative. The simple way to do it is a `while`-style loop, shifting left by one until the MSB is where you want.

[Algorithm for finding the smallest power of two that's greater or equal to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364985/algorithm-for-finding-the-smallest-power-of-two-thats-greater-or-equal-to-a-give) has some alternate possibilities if you want something faster (nothing for MIPS though).