# C macro to get the smallest power of two greater than a given number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, c-preprocessor

I need a C macro to get the smallest of power two greater than a given number.

For example, `FIRSTFREEBIT(0x16)` (binary `1_0110`) must be equal to `0x20`.

I am going to use it as:

```
#include <someheader.h> // defines SOME_X and SOME_Y
enum {
     x = SOME_X,
     y = SOME_Y,
     z = FIRSTFREEBIT(x|y),
     t = z << 1,
};
```

A similar, but slightly different SO question:
[Algorithm for finding the smallest power of two that's greater or equal to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364985/algorithm-for-finding-the-smallest-power-of-two-thats-greater-or-equal-to-a-giv)

Comment: [this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i or http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/nlz.c.txt - you just have to encode it as a macro.

Comment: Should (binary 1_0000) return 0x10 or 0x20?  Base on "smallest of power two greater than", sounds like you want 0x20.

Comment: I think you mean `t = 1U << z`

Comment: @chux yes, I want FIRSTFREEBIT(0x10) to be 0x20, because I want a bit that has not yet been used.

Comment: @rici: if `SOME_X` is 2 and `SOME_Y` is 4, `x` must be 2, `y` must be 4, `z` must be 8, and `t` must be 16. That is, `z` must be a value with the first-yet-unused bit set, rather than the number of that bit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my code, you are welcome to invent something better:

```
#define __OR_RSHIFT__(n,x) ((x)|(x)>>n)
#define FIRST_UNUSED_BIT(x) (1+__OR_RSHIFT__(16,__OR_RSHIFT__(8,__OR_RSHIFT__(4,__OR_RSHIFT__(2,__OR_RSHIFT__(1,x))))))
```

Comment: Identifiers starting with two underscores are reserved by language standard for internal needs. You should not use them.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `__builtin_clz` GCC intrinsic. It will give you the number of leading zero bits, which could be used to determine the position of the first bit set. Then do a left bit shift of `1`, times the position.

Comment: The best thing is that it works at compile-time! But: it should be `1+__builtin_ffs(x)`

Comment: oops! `__builtin_ffs(0x5)=0x1`, that is, it must be a different function!

Comment: Ah yes, the `ffs` function returns the position of the first least significant bit that is set. `__builtin_clz` returns the number of leading zero bits and could do your job.

Comment: It is `1<<0x20-__builtin_clz(x)`

Comment: Also make sure to handle the case when `x` is zero, because `clz` would return an undefined result in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a compile-time solution that takes advantage of the GCC _builtin_clz function:

```
// Lowest Power of 2 greater than or equal to x.  Assumes integer x greater
// than 0
#define LPO2(x) (1<<((sizeof(x)*8)-__builtin_clz((x)-1)))

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", LPO2(7)); // => 8
    printf("%d\n", LPO2(8)); // => 8
    printf("%d\n", LPO2(9)); // => 16
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie Good catch -- thank you and edited.