# How can I get the position of the most significant bit in a number?

Tags: bit

I know that when getting the least significant bit in a number is by doing `x &= -x`.  This clears out all the other bits except the least set one.  I'm just wondering now how can I easily get the most significant bit.  I can come up with a bit shifting code, but probably not ideal in terms of complexity.

Comment: Uh, the easiest way to get the least significant bit is probably just `x&1`

Comment: floor(log2(value)). Complexity for whom? What language, what platform?

Comment: Which language?? Any _real_ tags? Most/least in the _type_ or most/least _set in a particular number_? Your wording is quite vague.

Comment: Related: [Algorithm for finding the smallest power of two that's greater or equal to a given value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/364985/4279)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <climits>

// have the compiler determine how many bits we need to right shift so only
// the biggest will be left
constexpr unsigned shiftby = 1<<(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned)-1);
// then at runtime: shift it.
unsigned result = static_cast<unsigned>(x)>>shiftby;
```

While this appears complex, at runtime it's literally just a single shift operation.  This only works for types `int` and `unsigned`.

Comment: Nice C++ solution for finding the most significant bit in this particular type, but I suspect the OP really wants the MSbit in a given _number_, based on the earlier phrase "least set".